# Как отследить перемещение одного окна над другим?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Меня очень интересует, как, например, в браузере google chrome (и не только) вкладка помещается в другое окно при перетаскивании? Это ведь не DragDrop. Что тогда? Все события мыши передаются только в то окно, которое я тащу, тогда как мне определить, что курсор мыши находится на панели вкладок другого окна, которое под перетаскиваемым?

Просьба не давать ссылки на готовые контролы табов, в которых это реализовано. Ну или с конкретным файлом и строкой. Потому что я пытался найти в них, как это реализовано, но не смог (на гитхабе).

Comment: А в чём проблема? Подписываетесь на MouseDown, выставляете флаг. Если при выставленом флаге пришло MouseMove, у вас перетаскивание. На MouseUp убираете флаг. Анализируете координаты и перемещаете таб программно.

Comment: Вам придётся программно поменять capture на целевое окно, когда мышь переходи к нему. Тогда координаты и события мыши станут приходить в новое окно.

Comment: Влад, а откуда я узнаю, что мышь находится над тем или иным окном, если их, например, десяток и все частично перекрываются другими?

Comment: `BestTarget(Point screenPoint)` возвращает самое верхнее окно, которое содержит данную точку. Учитывая перекрытия.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну вот вам пример.

Для начала, создадим окно, которое умеет определять, какому из экземпляров принадлежит точка на экране. Положим в окно контейнер для перемещаемых элементов.

```
<Window x:Class="CrossWindowDrop.DropContainerWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas x:Name="Arena"/>
</Window>
```

(Код, работающий с Z-порядком, взят из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3473908/276994).)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace CrossWindowDrop
{
    public partial class DropContainerWindow : Window
    {
        public DropContainerWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // добавить перемещаемый элемент
        public void AcceptActor(Actor actor)
        {
            Arena.Children.Add(actor);
        }

        // убрать перемещаемый элемент
        public void ReleaseActor(Actor actor)
        {
            Arena.Children.Remove(actor);
        }

        // найти самое верхнее окно для данной точки
        public static DropContainerWindow BestTarget(Point screenPoint)
        {
            return AllByZOrder().FirstOrDefault(w =>
                {
                    var arena = w.Arena;
                    var arenaPoint = arena.PointFromScreen(screenPoint);
                    return arenaPoint.X >= 0 &&
                           arenaPoint.Y >= 0 &&
                           arenaPoint.X < arena.ActualWidth &&
                           arenaPoint.Y < arena.ActualHeight;
                });
        }

        // получить список всех окон, отсортированный по Z-порядку
        // для обхода окон приходится использовать WinAPI, т. к.
        // WPF не знает о Z-порядке
        static IEnumerable<DropContainerWindow> AllByZOrder()
        {
            var byHandle = App.Current.Windows
                    .OfType<DropContainerWindow>()
                    .ToDictionary(w => ((HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(w))
                                           .Handle);

            for (IntPtr hWnd = GetTopWindow(IntPtr.Zero);
                 hWnd != IntPtr.Zero;
                 hWnd = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT))
            {
                DropContainerWindow w;
                if (byHandle.TryGetValue(hWnd, out w))
                    yield return w;
            }
        }

        // вспомогательные WinAPI-функции и константы
        const uint GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;
        [DllImport("user32")]
        static extern IntPtr GetTopWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32")]
        static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint wCmd);
    }
}
```

Теперь, сам перемещаемый элемент. Реализуем его как `UserControl`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="CrossWindowDrop.Actor"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Height="50" Width="50" MouseDown="OnMouseDown" MouseUp="OnMouseUp">
</UserControl>
```

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace CrossWindowDrop
{
    public partial class Actor : UserControl
    {
        public Actor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // эти три свойства валидны лишь на время движения

        // запоминает позицию мыши внутри контрола
        Point relativeMousePos;
        // контейнер
        FrameworkElement parent;
        // окно, в котором мы находимся в данный момент
        DropContainerWindow window;

        // на нажатии мыши начинаем движение
        void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            parent = (FrameworkElement)this.Parent;
            window = (DropContainerWindow)Window.GetWindow(this);
            relativeMousePos = e.GetPosition(this);
            // подписываемся на перемещение мыши
            MouseMove += OnDragMove;
            // и захватываем mouse capture
            Mouse.Capture(this);
        }

        // при отпускании мыши прекращаем движение
        void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // отписываемся от перемещения мыши
            MouseMove -= OnDragMove;
            // обновляем наше местоположение
            UpdatePosition(e);
            // отпускаем mouse capture
            Mouse.Capture(null);
            window = null;
            parent = null;
        }

        void OnDragMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdatePosition(e);
        }

        void UpdatePosition(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // абсолютное положение точки на экране
            var screenPoint = PointToScreen(relativeMousePos);
            // находим наиболее подходящее окно
            var bestWindow = DropContainerWindow.BestTarget(screenPoint);
            // если мы надо окном, и это не текущее окно...
            if (bestWindow != null && bestWindow != window)
                MigrateTo(bestWindow); // ... переезжаем!
            // позиция мыши относительно нашего контейнера
            var point = e.GetPosition(parent);
            // перемещаемся в нужную позицию
            Canvas.SetLeft(this, point.X - relativeMousePos.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(this, point.Y - relativeMousePos.Y);
        }

        // самое интересное: переезд в новое окно
        void MigrateTo(DropContainerWindow newWindow)
        {
            // отпускаем мышь - наш контрол пересоздастся в другом окне
            Mouse.Capture(null);
            // просим наше окно выписать отпустить нас
            window.ReleaseActor(this);
            // а новое - принять
            newWindow.AcceptActor(this);
            // подправляем наши свойства
            parent = (FrameworkElement)this.Parent;
            window = newWindow;
            // и снова захватываем мышь
            Mouse.Capture(this);
            // вот и всё
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и добавьте главную программу по вкусу.

```
<Application x:Class="CrossWindowDrop.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</Application>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace CrossWindowDrop
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            var w1 = new DropContainerWindow() { Title = "Window 1" };
            var actor1 = new Actor() { Background = Brushes.Violet };
            var actor2 = new Actor() { Background = Brushes.Green };
            Canvas.SetLeft(actor2, 50);
            w1.AcceptActor(actor1);
            w1.AcceptActor(actor2);
            w1.Show();
            new DropContainerWindow() { Title = "Window 2" }.Show();
            new DropContainerWindow() { Title = "Window 3" }.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Всё! Теперь вы можете таскать цветные квадраты из одного окна в другое.

Comment: Спасибо! static IEnumerable<DropContainerWindow> AllByZOrder() - это то что было нужно! ))