# TreeView, как переместить итем с одногой ноды в другую? C#\WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Во общем пытаюсь реализовать файловый експлорер, уже почти все сделал, но тут какая то непонятная ситуация у меня...

Когда я пытаюсь переместить ноду(то есть как бы файл перемещаю из одной папки в другую), вот таким вот кодом:

```
...
TreeViewItem node; // Node to move
TreeViewItem oldFolder = (TreeViewItem)node.Parent;
oldFolder.Items.Remove(node);
newFolder.Items.Add(node);
...
```

То итем теряет все байндинги и обработчики ивентов этого итема...

Вопрос:  Как переместить `TreeViewItem` в `TreeView` так, что бы этот итем сохранил все свои свойства байндинги ивенты и все остальное, то есть как скопировать `TreeViewItem` в другой `TreeViewItem`?

**UPDATE1:**
Ну может быть совсем уж все не теряет, но те на которые подписываюсь я - теряет...
Вот как у меня все устроено:
Стиль итема

```
<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
<Setter.Value>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="HeaderTemplateKey">
        <StackPanel x:Name="PART_InnerPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    Height="20">
            <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderText" Text="{Binding}" Margin="7,1,0,0" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableHeader" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=HeaderText}" 
                    Margin="2,2"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    Visibility="{Binding IsEdit, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:MyTreeViewItem}},
                Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
```

Потом в классе ноды я получаю `PART_EditableHeader` и подписываюсь на его ивенты, вот код этого всего:

```
public TextBox EditableHeader;
public void MyTreeViewItem_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContentPresenter headerContentPreseter = this.Template.FindName("PART_Header", this) as ContentPresenter;
        if (headerContentPreseter != null)
        {
                EditableHeader = this.HeaderTemplate.FindName("PART_EditableHeader", headerContentPreseter) as TextBox;
        }
        LayoutUpdated -= MyTreeViewItem_LayoutUpdated;
        OnHeaderLoaded();
    }

    void OnHeaderLoaded()
    {
        if (EditableHeader != null)
        {
            KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler preselect = delegate
            {
                // Do work...
            };
            EditableHeader.PreviewGotKeyboardFocus += preselect;
            EditableHeader.GotKeyboardFocus += preselect;
            EditableHeader.PreviewMouseDown += (s, e) =>
            {
                // Do work...
            };
            EditableHeader.LostFocus += delegate
            {
                // Do work...
            };
            EditableHeader.PreviewMouseDoubleClick += (s, e) =>
            {
                // Do work...
            };
        }
    }
```

И все как бы работает нормально, до первого перемещения ноды, как только я перемещаю сразу перестают работать все обработчики описанные в методе `OnHeaderLoaded()`. Пока что по дебагу такое ощущение что мне нужно просто обновить еще раз `EditableHeader`, но почему-то когда пытаюсь обновить тем же способом то получаю `ContentPresenter headerContentPreseter == null`...

Короче я уже ничего не понимаю почему оно не работает... Помогите разобраться...

**UPDATE2:**
Вот как биндится:

```
    var tabItem = new TabItem();
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    Binding b = new Binding
    {
        Source = node,
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
        Path = new PropertyPath(TreeViewNode.HeaderProperty)
    };
    tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);

    b = new Binding
    {
        Source = node,
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
        Path = new PropertyPath(TreeViewNode.PathProperty)
    };
    tabItem.SetBinding(TabItem.ToolTipTextProperty, b);
```

Comment: Совсем все event'ы он терять не может. Можете сообразить минимальный воспроизводящий пример?

Comment: Судя по всему, при перемещении вызывается Unloaded и потом снова Loaded. И повторно применяется Template. Я бы на вашем месте подписался на OnApplyTemplate или что-то подобное, и перечитывал `EditableHeader`. (Вот [немного почитать](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/04/template-part-tips/) близко к теме.)

Comment: @VladD, Был занят неделю, вот появилось время, ну и во общем я попробовал подписаться на `OnApplyTemplate` и там получаю исключение `this.HeaderTemplate.FindName("PART_EditableHeader", header) threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'`...

Comment: Хм, странно. А что внутри исключения? Может быть, что-то полезное найдётся?

Comment: Вроде кажись нашел решение, поменял обновление элементов с `LayoutUpdated` на `Loaded` и вроде теперь получается так: Я удаляю ноду - вызывается `Unloaded`, потом я добавляю эту ноду в другую ноду и вызывается `Loaded` этой ноды, и в этом ивенте я обновляю все элементы, и теперь работают все байндинги и все во обще вроде заработало как нужно, сейчас еще подебажу посмотрю может где то еще будет баг, но пока что выглядит как будто все нормльно работает. Почему не работало при `OnApplyTemplate` я так и не понял, в исключении ничего нету..

Comment: @VladD, Все таки нашел баг один, у ноды есть `Dependency property` - `Path` и к нему байндится `TextBlock.TextProperty` в моей программе, но когда нода удаляется(теряет родителя) то этот байндинг слетает и больше не работает... Но когда я перемещаю как бы файлы вместе с папкой, то есть перемещаю ноду-родителя полностью, вместе с вложенными нодами, то тогда все работает нормально, и байндинги не слетают...

Comment: А как именно биндится? Покажите код.

Comment: А, тогда понятно, в чём причина. Вы ведь пишете: `Source = node`, видите? При переносе элемента, понятно, `node` сам по себе не изменится. Так что он всё ещё ссылается на старый, «мёртвый» экземпляр `node`. Вам нужно обновить его вручную, раз вы переставляете его таким образом.

Comment: Я не совсем понял, а как именно мне обновить? Вручную забиндить еще раз?

Comment: Именно так. У вас в этот момент должно быть правильное обновлённое значение `node`.

Comment: Жаль что нету другого способа, как то сохранить все байндинги перед удалением ноды и потом восстановить их обратно, ибо теряется весь смысл байндинга, если мне нужно вручную перебайндить то с таким же успехом я могу хранить мой объект как свойство ноды, и вручную менять свойства этого объекта при изминении определенных свойств ноды, или тупо в ноде создать ивент, например `NodeUpdated`, подписать на него метод моего объекта и уже там все поменять передав ноду аргументом этого ивента.

Comment: Ну, это да. Для начала проверьте, чтобы так работало. А потом можно, по идее, попробовать написать байндинг по-другому, чтобы он обновлялся автоматически.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29411/discussion-between-skydancer-and-vladd).

Answer (score 1):

> итем теряет все байндинги и обработчики ивентов этого итема...

Не надо менять UI вручную. В обработчике мыши надо получить контейнер, извлечь из него элемент данных, после этого вызвать DoDragDrop, и если не было отмены сброса, удалить элемент из источника данных.
Пример переноса изображения между двумя контролами в WPF - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/477112/3).

Comment: `DoDragDrop`? Как-то сильно сложно, мы ж таскаем контрол внутри своего же приложения, а не данные из другого приложения. [Вот тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444924/10105) вроде попроще.

Comment: @VladD _"DoDragDrop? Как-то сильно сложно, мы ж таскаем контрол внутри своего же приложения"_ -- а что сложно? экспортировать и обращаться к WinAPI не надо. вся логика в одном методе *_PreviewMouseMove. метод небольшой, и его можно использовать в разных ситуациях.

Comment: Код получается сложнее, и делать приходится много лишнего. Например, приходится оформлять format, который по сути не нужен.

Comment: @VladD _"делать приходится много лишнего. ... приходится оформлять format, который по сути не нужен"_  -- необязательно. format можно использовать стандартный. зависит от ситуации. а насчет лишнего - попробуйте написать программу, которая позволяет перетаскивать данные между разными контролами, а также поддерживает сброс данных извне.

Comment: Если нужен дроп из других приложений — то да. А если просто перетаскивание контролов внутри приложения, то пример из первого комментария концептуально вроде проще.

Answer (score 0):

*Вынесено из комментариев:*

Причина в коде `Source = node`. При переносе элемента, понятно, `node` сам по себе не изменится. Так что он всё ещё ссылается на старый, «мёртвый» экземпляр `node`. Вам нужно обновить его вручную, раз вы переставляете его таким образом.

Ещё лучше было бы вовсе отказаться от ручного `Binding`'а, перенести его в XAML, а добавлением/удалением элементов заниматься на уровне VM: изменение коллекции VM-элементов в folder'е должно автоматически приводить к добавлению/удалению UI-элементов.