# Drag&Drop по правилам WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, drag-n-drop

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать правильно drag&drop прибиндив его положение к MVVM, чтоб можно было бы его сохранить в файл просеарилизировав в JSON? Я знаю как это всё делается по "старинке", поставить событие на Mouse_Down, Mouse_Move и Mouse_Up, а когда происходит перетаскивание в Mouse_Move делать на подобии "canvas.setleft(uiobj, canvas.getleft(uiobj)+mouse.x)" (этот пример не будет работать я знаю), а вот как в mvvm всё это переделать я не знаю :-(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот хороший туториал: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/420545/WPF-Drag-and-Drop-MVVM-using-Behavior. Я делал по нему

Comment: К вашей ситуации **не подходит** скорее всего, но может быть полезно тому кто ищет по ключевым словам *drag&drop*. Я когда-то делал _drag&drop_ для перемещения элементов списков по [этому туториалу](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43614/Drag-and-Drop-in-WPF) и был доволен.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Смотрите. Давайте поделим всё на визуальную и модельную части.

Визуальная часть занимается перетаскиванием. При определении факта начала перетаскивания нужно отвязаться от VM (проще всего, наверное, скрыть элемент и показать на его месте другой, заодно можно немного поменять его вид, например, на полупрозрачный), обработать перетаскивание через MouseMove/MouseUp, определить, куда был дропнут элемент, отослать новые координаты в VM, и снова включить отображение элемента.

VM обновит данные, новые координаты вступят в силу через привязку.

Всё.

---

Написал простой пример MVVM-приложения с перетаскиванием. Приложение рисует набор из перетаскиваемых квадратов. Программа простая, поэтому я обхожусь без модели. Будет выглядеть так:

[image: draggable squares]

Начинаем с VM. Общий суперкласс, чтобы не имплементировать INPC каждый раз (если вы пользуетесь MVVM-фреймворком, у вас наверняка такой уже определён):

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Теперь класс, представляющий собой фигуру. Мы выкладываем публичные свойства с текущим значением позиции, и командой для смены позиции. Если вы будете сериализировать этот объект, не забудьте отметить команду несериализируемой.

```
class SquareVM : VM
{
    public SquareVM()
    {
        RequestMove = new SimpleCommand<Point>(MoveTo);
    }

    // стандартное свойство
    Point position;
    public Point Position
    {
        get { return position; }
        set { if (position != value) { position = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    // выставляем команду, которая занимается перемещением
    public ICommand RequestMove { get; }

    void MoveTo(Point newPosition)
    {
        // в реальности тут могут быть всякие проверки, конечно
        Position = newPosition;
    }
}
```

Я использую примитивнейший вариант команды:

```
class SimpleCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<T> onExecute;
    public SimpleCommand(Action<T> onExecute) { this.onExecute = onExecute; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
    public void Execute(object parameter) => onExecute((T)parameter);
}
```

Теперь, главная VM, ничего особенного:

```
class MainVM : VM
{
    public ObservableCollection<SquareVM> Squares { get; } =
        new ObservableCollection<SquareVM>()
        {
            new SquareVM() { Position = new Point( 30,  30) },
            new SquareVM() { Position = new Point(100,  70) },
            new SquareVM() { Position = new Point( 80,   0) },
            new SquareVM() { Position = new Point( 90, 180) },
            new SquareVM() { Position = new Point(200, 200) }
        };
}
```

На этом с VM-частью покончено.

Теперь, приложение. Стандартная заготовка для MVVM: App.xaml без `StartupUri` и переопределение `OnStartup`:

```
<Application x:Class="MvvmDraggable.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</Application>
```

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    MainVM mainVM = new MainVM();

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        new MainWindow() { DataContext = mainVM }.Show();
    }
}
```

Переходим к интересной части: представление.

Окно отображает список элементов в `Canvas`'е. Для привязки списка элементов использован, как обычно, `ItemsControl`:

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmDraggable.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmDraggable"
        Title="Draggable squares" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Squares}" Width="300" Height="300"
                      Background="Beige">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <!-- хост списка элементов - канвас, чтобы можно было
                         произвольно устанавливать координаты -->
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- сам квадрат вынесем в отдельный UserControl -->
                    <local:DraggableSquare/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <!-- а это привязка координат контейнера к VM -->
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Position.X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Position.Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Сам контрол тоже несложен, код для обработки мышиных сообщений я честно стащил из ответа на вопрос «[Как отследить перемещение одного окна над другим?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444924/10105)» и выкинул всё ненужное.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MvvmDraggable.DraggableSquare"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Width="50" Height="50"
             MouseDown="OnMouseDown" MouseUp="OnMouseUp"
             Background="Green">
    <Grid/>
</UserControl>
```

Маленькая тонкость: чтобы не следить за командой в `DataContext`'е, я объявил `DependencyProperty` `RequestMoveCommand`, и установил `Binding` на него. Также мы подписались в XAML'е на `MouseDown` и `MouseUp`.

```
public partial class DraggableSquare : UserControl
{
    public DraggableSquare()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // устанавливаем Binding RequestMove из VM на свойство RequestMoveCommand:
        SetBinding(RequestMoveCommandProperty, new Binding("RequestMove"));
    }

    // стандартное DependencyProperty
    #region dp ICommand RequestMoveCommand
    public ICommand RequestMoveCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(RequestMoveCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RequestMoveCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RequestMoveCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RequestMoveCommand", typeof(ICommand),
                                    typeof(DraggableSquare));
    #endregion

    Vector relativeMousePos; // смещение мыши от левого верхнего угла квадрата
    Canvas container;        // канвас-контейнер

    // по нажатию на левую клавишу начинаем следить за мышью
    void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        container = FindParent<Canvas>();
        relativeMousePos = e.GetPosition(this) - new Point();
        MouseMove += OnDragMove;
        LostMouseCapture += OnLostCapture;
        Mouse.Capture(this);
    }

    // клавиша отпущена - завершаем процесс
    void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FinishDrag(sender, e);
        Mouse.Capture(null);
    }

    // потеряли фокус (например, юзер переключился в другое окно) - завершаем тоже
    void OnLostCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        FinishDrag(sender, e);
    }

    void OnDragMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePosition(e);
    }

    void FinishDrag(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseMove -= OnDragMove;
        LostMouseCapture -= OnLostCapture;
        UpdatePosition(e);
    }

    // требуем у VM обновить позицию через команду
    void UpdatePosition(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = e.GetPosition(container);
        // не забываем проверку на null
        RequestMoveCommand?.Execute(point - relativeMousePos);
    }

    // это вспомогательная функция, ей место в общей библиотеке
    private T FindParent<T>() where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        FrameworkElement current = this;
        T t;
        do
        {
            t = current as T;
            current = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        }
        while (t == null && current != null);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Теперь совсем всё!

---

[Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618048/10105) модификация этого кода, чтобы вместо квадратов таскался их уменьшенный и полупрозрачный предпросмотр.

Comment: А что вы имеете в виду под "При определении факта начала перетаскивания нужно отвязаться от VM"?
P.S. Всё таки решил, что нужно разобраться с MVVM, рано или поздно всё равно пригодится.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Ну, если у вас свойства/координаты определяются через привязку к VM, то нужно (временно) убрать эту зависимость каким-то образом. А про обработку перетаскивания у меня где-то был ответ с кодом.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Вот тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444924/10105 (там можно выбросить `MigrateTo` и `Actor`'ов, они нужны только для переезда в новое окно).

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Я написал рабочий пример, сейчас отлажу и запощу.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Написал, пробуйте.

Comment: Спасибочки, я завтра после школы посмотрю и разберу ^_^

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD, объясните, пожалуйста, для чего ObservableCollection нужен геттер. Почему с ним работает Ваш пример, а без него нет?

Comment: @maxwell: Потому что `Binding` производится только к свойствам, не к полям.

Answer (score 2):

Как сделать это без "многокода" с использованием Catel (https://github.com/Catel/Catel),
добавляем этот namespace: xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com"

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <catel:DragDrop>
                    <catel:DragDrop.DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="И уносят меня!"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </catel:DragDrop.DataTemplate>
                </catel:DragDrop>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </ItemsControl>
```

в DragDrop.DataTemplate вы можете определить любой шаблон элемента который будет 'перетягиватся':

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ну а если Elements == ObservableCollection<> (более точно INotifyCollectionChanged), то подписываемся на ее событие во VM...и делаем все что нужно для обработки события изменения коллекции в результате DnD.

**P.S.** не считаю вопрос [Перемещение контролов по ItemsControl с использованием MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1045326/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-itemscontrol-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-mvvm/) дублирующим, потому что данный вопрос более общий, а тот более прикладной... (никто не будет в рабочем проекте изобретать велосипед) так же смотрите ответ здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1045363/358860