# Изменение размера UI объекта мышью UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Как можно ресайзить, например, картинку при помощи мыши? Пока реализовал только двумя пальцами, но на пк такое не сработает. Думал по хождению курсора смотреть, но у меня еще перемещение по странице есть, поэтому картинка начинает перемещаться

Код для зума

```
private void Image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var image = sender as Border;
        Point mousePos = Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition;
        var ct = (CompositeTransform)image.RenderTransform;

         if (image.BorderThickness == new Thickness(5,5,5,5))
        {
            if (mousePos.X> pos.X|| mousePos.Y > pos.Y)
            {
                ct.ScaleX *= 1.005;
                ct.ScaleY *= 1.005;
            }
            if (mousePos.X < pos.X || mousePos.Y < pos.Y)
            {
                ct.ScaleX /= 1.005;
                ct.ScaleY /= 1.005;
            }
    }
 private void ImageBorder_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pos = Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition;
    }

    private void ImageBorder_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pos = Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition;
    }
```

Этот код работает, только для пальцев. Хочу чтобы по нажатию на картинку, она как-то выделялась и появлялись эти контролы(ресайз, вращение)

Добавил рамку на `XAML`

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Collage">
 <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
  RightTapped="Image_RightTapped"
  DoubleTapped="Image_DoubleTapped"
  PointerExited="Image_PointerExited"
  PointerEntered="Image_PointerEntered" 
  ManipulationDelta="Image_ManipulationDelta"
  PointerWheelChanged="Image_PointerWheelChanged" 
  ManipulationMode="TranslateX, TranslateY,Rotate,Scale"
  Tapped="Image_Tapped"
  >
  <Border.RenderTransform>
     <CompositeTransform/>
  </Border.RenderTransform>
       <Image
         Width="672"           
         Source="{x:Bind Image}"
         Margin="{x:Bind Position}">                
        </Image>
 </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Методы имеют неправильно название, но реализация изменена для `Border`. Получается тот же функционал, но почему `Border` накладывается НА картинку а не ВОКРУГ нее?

Comment: А как у вас реализовано изменение размера пальцами? Код можно легко адаптировать по идее.

Comment: Через Composite Transform(не уверен что точно написал, пока нет под рукой студии), а там scaleX и Y. Проблема больше в том чтобы выделить саму картинку и потащить за край ее. Сегодня пробовал через колесико менять размер, но тоже не особо вышло.

Comment: Ну, Transform — это-то понятно, а вот как вы обрабатываете событие изменения размера, это нетривиально.

Comment: Manipulation delta и использую аргумент е. Но это работает только для пальцев, даже на симуляторе не получается использовать

Comment: Ну так вы бы добавили код в вопрос, чтобы было понятно, что у вас уже есть, а что ещё нужно сделать.

Comment: @VladD добавил код

Comment: Окей, хорошо. Теперь следующий вопрос: как должно происходить увеличение? Нажать мышкой и потянуть? Например, за край? А если нажать в середине и потянуть?

Comment: @VladD я обновил код, теперь по нажатию на картинку появляется рамка синяя и за нее нужно тянуть, чтобы изменить размер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На основе ответа VladD, реализовал изменение размера на Uwp.

По вхождению на `Border` определяется какой тип курсора показать. Дальше через большую конструкцию `if` определяем с какой стороны мы будем ресайзить. В самой реализации будет несколько строк. Пример для ресайза правой стороны картинки

```
  private void Image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       var grid = sender as Grid;
        grid.Height = grid.ActualHeight;
        grid.Width = grid.ActualWidth;
        if(this.isRightSide)
        {
         grid.Width += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        }
    }
```

Соответственно, если тащите за низ, то меняете У, если за угол, то оба параметра

Результат работы:

[image: Результат]

Answer (score 1):

Окей, я набросал решение на WPF, надеюсь, что оно легко перенесётся и на UWP.

Во-первых, я в XAML'е поменял `RenderTransform` на `LayoutTransform` (надеюсь, это ничего не сломает).

```
<Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="5"
        Width="100" Height="100"
        MouseDown="OnBorderMouseDown" MouseUp="OnBorderMouseUp">
    <Border.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform/>
    </Border.LayoutTransform>
    <Image Source="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f81585f940e68c3bab934cc6f59c901e?s=328" />
</Border>
```

Затем, я дал имя `Container` контейнеру, в котором лежит `Border`. В принципе, вместо него можно взять что угодно, что не меняет размера. Например, всю страницу.

Дальше код. Он идейно основан на этом [более простом коде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647/10105), но с переработанными вычислениями.

Итак, код:

```
Border draggedBorder; // элемент, который мы изменяем
Size originalSize, originalTransformedSize; // первоначальный размер, а также
                                            // размер в начале перетаскивания
Point originalCenterRelativeToContainer;    // позиция центра относительно контейнера
Vector originalMouseOffsetFromCenter;       // позиция мыши относительно центра картинки
                                            // в начале перетаскивания

enum Direction { Left, Top, Right, Bottom }
// какую из сторон сейчас тащим
HashSet<Direction> draggedSide = new HashSet<Direction>();

void OnBorderMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // запомним, что мы тянем
    draggedBorder = (Border)sender;
    // запомним оригинальный размер, он нам ещё понадобится
    originalSize = draggedBorder.RenderSize;

    var localCenter = new Point(draggedBorder.ActualHeight / 2,
                                draggedBorder.ActualWidth / 2);
    // неподвижная точка - центр картинки относительно её контейнера
    originalCenterRelativeToContainer =
        draggedBorder.TranslatePoint(localCenter, Container);

    var mouseOffset = GetMouseOffsetFromCenter(e);
    var transformedSize = GetTransformedSize(draggedBorder);

    // выясним, какую сторону тащим (или какИЕ сторонЫ)
    draggedSide.Clear();
    if (mouseOffset.X < 0 && -mouseOffset.X > transformedSize.Width / 2 - 5)
        draggedSide.Add(Direction.Left);
    if (mouseOffset.X > 0 && mouseOffset.X > transformedSize.Width / 2 - 5)
        draggedSide.Add(Direction.Right);
    if (mouseOffset.Y < 0 && -mouseOffset.Y > transformedSize.Height / 2 - 5)
        draggedSide.Add(Direction.Top);
    if (mouseOffset.Y > 0 && mouseOffset.Y > transformedSize.Height / 2 - 5)
        draggedSide.Add(Direction.Bottom);

    originalMouseOffsetFromCenter = mouseOffset;
    originalTransformedSize = transformedSize;

    // подпишемся на перемещение мыши
    MouseMove += OnDragMove;
    // прикрепим фокус к нам, чтобы не ушёл
    Mouse.Capture(draggedBorder);
}

void OnBorderMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // отпишемся от перемещения мыши
    MouseMove -= OnDragMove;
    // обновимся в последний раз
    UpdateTransform(e);
    // отпустим фокус
    Mouse.Capture(null);
    // подчистим
    draggedSide.Clear();
    draggedBorder = null;
}

void OnDragMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // мышь двинулась => обновимся
    UpdateTransform(e);
}

void UpdateTransform(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // подсчитаем новые расстояния до краёв
    var mouseOffset = GetMouseOffsetFromCenter(e);
    var newSize = originalTransformedSize;

    if (draggedSide.Contains(Direction.Left))
    {
        if (mouseOffset.X > 0)
            mouseOffset.X = 0;
        var diff = originalMouseOffsetFromCenter.X - mouseOffset.X;
        newSize.Width += diff * 2;
    }

    if (draggedSide.Contains(Direction.Right))
    {
        if (mouseOffset.X < 0)
            mouseOffset.X = 0;
        var diff = mouseOffset.X - originalMouseOffsetFromCenter.X;
        newSize.Width += diff * 2;
    }

    if (draggedSide.Contains(Direction.Top))
    {
        if (mouseOffset.Y > 0)
            mouseOffset.Y = 0;
        var diff = originalMouseOffsetFromCenter.Y - mouseOffset.Y;
        newSize.Height += diff * 2;
    }

    if (draggedSide.Contains(Direction.Bottom))
    {
        if (mouseOffset.Y < 0)
            mouseOffset.Y = 0;
        var diff = mouseOffset.Y - originalMouseOffsetFromCenter.Y;
        newSize.Height += diff * 2;
    }

    var transform = (ScaleTransform)draggedBorder.LayoutTransform;
    transform.ScaleX = newSize.Width / originalSize.Width;
    transform.ScaleY = newSize.Height / originalSize.Height;
}

Size GetTransformedSize(FrameworkElement fe)
{
    var t = fe.LayoutTransform;
    var topleft = t.Transform(new Point());
    var bottomright = t.Transform(new Point(fe.ActualWidth, fe.ActualHeight));
    return new Size(bottomright.X - topleft.X, bottomright.Y - topleft.Y);
}

Vector GetMouseOffsetFromCenter(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var positionRelativeToContainer = e.GetPosition(Container);
    return positionRelativeToContainer - originalCenterRelativeToContainer;
}
```

Я старался комментировать по коду, где может быть неясно.

Результат:

[image: меняем размеры]

Comment: Так, методы `OnBorderMouseDown` `OnBorderMouseUp ` заменил на `PointerPressed` и `PointerReleased`, но `MouseButtonEventArgs` вообще не находит студия, так же нельзя создать переменную типа `Vector`, заменил на `Point`, но главная поблема остается в аргументе

Comment: @SmiLe: Ну, а какой тип аргументов приходит на `PointerPressed`? Его и берите. // Посмотрел: `PointerRoutedEventArgs`.

Comment: `LayoutTransform` тоже не видит и нельзя использовать переменную типа `Vector` http://joxi.ru/KAxY7lRiEQRzr8

Comment: Я обновил код в вопросе, просто поставив цифры и теперь можно ресайзить картинку просто потянув за нее. Но вот ее можно только увеличить, можно как то вместо констант получить значение передвижения мыши и относительно этого менять размер?

Comment: Получил позицию мыши на экране `Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition`, Теперь нужно при увеличении Х и У увеличивать, а при уменьшении уменьшать. Вот с эти проблема

Comment: Приделал пока такой костыль(см. код), вроде работает, но нужно отпустить мышку после ресайза. Можно как то улучшить код, чтобы сразу понимал в какую сторону двигаю

Comment: Реализовал ресайз как в Вашем примере, за исключением того, что я не могу увеличить картинку, если тянуть за верхний край или левый. Она должна увеличиваться только в том направлении, куда ее тащишь. Увеличиваю так: `image.Widht+=e.Delta.translation.X`, но так она увеличивается в правую сторону

Comment: @SmiLe: Ну, у меня в коде картинка раздвигается в обе стороны. Это за счёт того, что я делаю трансформацию относительно центра, а не левого верхнего угла.