# Использование команд в MVVM

Tags: wpf

Только начал изучать WPF и паттерн MVVM и возникло непонимание связанное с использованием команд, как в MVVM, так и вне его.

Нужно сделать, чтобы пользователь смог передвигать некий объект на форме. 
При реализации через события мне нужно было бы обрабатывать событие MouseMove,  MouseLeftButtonDown и MouseLeftButtonUp, чтобы объект перемещался только когда ЛКМ нажата на нем.

Но как это делается при реализации через команды?

Comment: Возможно нужно привязывать значения положения элемента на форме к переменным, а в методах (которые потом "привязываются") к командам обрабатывать значения.

Comment: DnD вполне можно оставить целиком на совести формы и не тащить в VM, если вам не нужна сложная логика (только поменять порядок в списке, например).

Comment: @Monk, Но получается, если этот объект создается в VM, то и события нужно тащить в VM?

Comment: Не обязательно. Из VM можно забиндить коллекцию, а вот таскать уже в формочке просто объекты любого типа. Не то чтобы это было совсем уж нормально, но и DND на уровне VM смотрится странно.

Comment: Дубликат? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647