# События в CustomControl

Tags: wpf

Делаю Drag&Drop по мотивам [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647/222188).

Есть `CustomControl`, который наследует от `ToggleButton`. 
Привязываю методы к событиям в конструкторе, но таким образом события не обрабатываются.

Как правильно сделать?

```
public class CustomControl: ToggleButton
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        this.MouseLeftButtonDown += OnMouseDown;
        this.MouseLeftButtonUp += OnMouseUp;
    }

    void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
     //...
    }

    void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
     //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class CustomControl : ToggleButton
{
      protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
      {
          base.OnMouseDown(e);
      }

      protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
      {
          base.OnMouseUp(e);
      }
}
```

Comment: Так работает, спасибо! А можете объяснить для чего мы так делаем?

Comment: @maxwell Если мы наследуется от контрола чтоб расширить или поменять его поведения то правильнее переопределять нужные методы стандартного контрола через override и там уже писать логику вашего контрола.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!