# Drag & Drop с предпросмотром

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Как сделать такой Drag&Drop с preview как на гифке при этом в рамках MVVM?

Есть `Canvas` с привязанной коллекцией объектов. Каждый объект представляет из себя `CustomControl` в котором уже реализован обычный Drag&Drop по примеру из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647/222188).

Думал при `MouseMove` делать `VisualBrush` текущего объекта, рисовать новый прямоугольник этой кистью и уже его перетаскивать. Но ведь `Canvas` привязан к коллекции и получается, что этот прямоугольник также нужно будет добавлять в коллекцию, чтобы он отобразился.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding itemsList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" Width="1000" Height="1000"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <local:CustomControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Position.X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Position.Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Давайте попробуем подправить код из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647/10105), чтобы он не переносил квадрат в реальности до тех пор, пока вы его не отпустите.

Идея с `VisualBrush` — хорошая, так нам будет легко «размножать» существующие элементы. А вот добавлять фиктивный элемент в коллекцию нехорошо, в конце-концов, у нас перемещение — забота UI-уровня, а не модели.

Поэтому изменений на VM-уровне не будет вовсе, и это хорошо.

Добавим поверх нашего списка квадратов ещё один уровень. Чтобы он не мешал, сделаем его прозрачным для мыши. Нужно будет привязать размеры обоих элементов, для этого нам понадобится имя и `Binding`:

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmDraggable2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmDraggable2"
        Title="Draggable squares 2" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Squares}" Width="300" Height="300"
                      Background="Beige" Name="DraggableItemsHost">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:DraggableSquare
                        DraggedImageContainer="{Binding ElementName=DraggedImageContainer}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Position.X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Position.Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Canvas IsHitTestVisible="False">
            <Rectangle Opacity="0.4" Name="DraggedImageContainer" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Добавилось имя у `ItemsControl`, у `DraggableSquare` появилась дополнительная привязка (о ней позже), и внизу появился `Canvas`, содержащий нужный элемент.

Далее, `DraggbleSquare`. Мы меняем немного нашу внутреннюю логику. `UpdatePosition` будет теперь вызываться только при отпускании мыши или потере фокуса окна.

```
void OnDragMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //UpdatePosition(e);
    UpdateDraggedSquarePosition(e);
}

void FinishDrag(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MouseMove -= OnDragMove;
    LostMouseCapture -= OnLostCapture;
    UpdatePosition(e);
    UpdateDraggedSquarePosition(null);
}
```

Новая часть логики: `UpdateDraggedSquarePosition`. Для неё нам понадобится новое dependency property `DraggedImageContainer`, в которое мы в XAML уже положили элемент, представляющий перемещающуюся картинку.

(Поместите это повыше, около `RequestMoveCommand`.)

```
#region dp Shape DraggedImageContainer
public Shape DraggedImageContainer
{
    get { return (Shape)GetValue(DraggedImageContainerProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DraggedImageContainerProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty DraggedImageContainerProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DraggedImageContainer", typeof(Shape), typeof(DraggableSquare));
#endregion
```

Собственно сама новая логика:

```
void UpdateDraggedSquarePosition(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var dragImageContainer = DraggedImageContainer;
    if (dragImageContainer == null)
        return;
    var needVisible = e != null;
    var wasVisible = dragImageContainer.Visibility == Visibility.Visible;
    // включаем/выключаем видимость перемещаемой картинки
    dragImageContainer.Visibility = needVisible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    if (!needVisible) // если мы выключились, нам больше нечего делать
        return;
    if (!wasVisible) // а если мы были выключены и включились,
    {                // нам надо привязать изображение себя
        dragImageContainer.Fill = new VisualBrush(this);
        dragImageContainer.SetBinding( // а также ширину/высоту
            Shape.WidthProperty,
            new Binding(nameof(ActualWidth)) { Source = this });
        dragImageContainer.SetBinding(
            Shape.HeightProperty,
            new Binding(nameof(ActualHeight)) { Source = this });
        // Binding нужен потому, что наш размер может по идее измениться
    }
    // перемещаем картинку на нужную позицию
    var parent = FindParent<Canvas>(dragImageContainer);
    var position = e.GetPosition(parent) - relativeMousePos;
    Canvas.SetLeft(dragImageContainer, position.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(dragImageContainer, position.Y);
}
```

Да, и мне пришлось немного поменять `GetParent`, чтобы он работал с произвольным элементом:

```
static private T FindParent<T>(FrameworkElement from) where T : FrameworkElement
{
    FrameworkElement current = from;
    T t;
    do
    {
        t = current as T;
        current = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    }
    while (t == null && current != null);
    return t;
}
```

и в `OnMouseDown` написать

```
container = FindParent<Canvas>(this);
```

Это всё.

Для того, чтобы получить красивую картинку, я ещё добавил цвет в `SquareVM`:

```
Color color;
public Color Color
{
    get { return color; }
    set { if (color != value) { color = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
}
```

и задал цвета в `MainVM`:

```
class MainVM : VM
{
    public ObservableCollection<SquareVM> Squares { get; } =
        new ObservableCollection<SquareVM>()
        {
            new SquareVM() { Position = new Point(30, 30),
                             Color = Color.FromRgb(0x3D, 0x31, 0x5B) },
            new SquareVM() { Position = new Point(100, 70),
                             Color = Color.FromRgb(0x44, 0x4B, 0x6E) },
            new SquareVM() { Position = new Point(80, 0),
                             Color = Color.FromRgb(0x70, 0x8B, 0x75) },
            new SquareVM() { Position = new Point(90, 180),
                             Color = Color.FromRgb(0x9A, 0xB8, 0x7A) },
            new SquareVM() { Position = new Point(200, 200),
                             Color = Color.FromRgb(0xF8, 0xF9, 0x91) }
        };
}
```

И ещё привязался к нему в `DraggableSquare.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MvvmDraggable2.DraggableSquare"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Width="50" Height="50"
             MouseDown="OnMouseDown" MouseUp="OnMouseUp">
    <UserControl.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
    </UserControl.Background>
    <Grid/>
</UserControl>
```

Получается вот что:

[image: а вот что получилось]

---

Если вы хотите, чтобы перемещаемая картинка была поменьше, проще всего уменьшить её через `RenderTransform`:

```
<Canvas IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <Rectangle Opacity="0.4" Name="DraggedImageContainer" Visibility="Collapsed"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```

[image: то же с трансформацией]

Comment: А разве размеры второй канвы не будут выставлены гридом? Зачем их указывать через биндинг?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Угу, будет. Это копипаст из реального кода, в котором реальная структура сложнее (и `ItemsControl`  с `Canvas`'ом не лежат в одном `Grid`'е, а есть ещё промежуточные слои). В данном случае, да, можно упростить.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Стоп, в этом случае не будет, из-за `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Squares}" Width="300" Height="300"`. Там явно указаны размеры.

Comment: Ну,  размеры можно и в грид перенести.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Хотя если убрать-таки привязку, всё равно работает правильно. Пересчёт координат от позиции, получается, не зависит. Какой умный код! :)