# Рисование мышкой фигур на элементе wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Можно ли реализовать отрисовку различных фигур с помощью мышки на каком-то элементе управления, например на этом:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Column="1" VisualElements="{Binding Visuals}" Name="chart" />
```

Данный элемент это LiveChart. Можно ли на примере прямоугольника показать, как реализовать отрисовку фигур мышкой?

Answer (score 5):

Ну вот вам пример. Учтите, что это не самый хороший пример, т. к. информация о том, что нарисовано, не уходит на уровень данных, а остаётся лишь в UI, как в WinForms.

UI будет очень простой. Мы будем рисовать на `Canvas`'е, т. к. он не двигает элементы и не производит никакого layout management'а, так что потом будет легко двигать уже нарисованные элементы по нему.

У `Canvas`'а добавим Background (чтобы он реагировал на мышь) и подпишемся на нажатие/отпускание/перемещение мыши:

```
<Canvas Name="DrawingTarget" Background="Transparent"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="DrawingMouseDown"
        MouseLeftButtonUp="DrawingMouseUp"
        MouseMove="DrawingMouseMove"/>
```

Теперь code-behind. Для начала, нам понадобится флаг, который будет говорить о том, мы в данный момент рисуем или нет.

```
bool isDrawing = false;
```

По нажатию мыши мы должны захватить мышь (чтобы даже при выходе за пределы контрола нам доставались мышиные события), перейти в режим рисования и начать новую фигуру. Стартовой точкой передадим точку, в которой произошёл клик:

```
void DrawingMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.Capture(DrawingTarget);
    isDrawing = true;
    StartFigure(e.GetPosition(DrawingTarget));
}
```

При перемещении мыши мы должны просто добавить ещё одну точку в фигуру. Ну и нужно не забыть проанализировать, находимся ли мы в режиме рисования:

```
void DrawingMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!isDrawing)
        return;
    AddFigurePoint(e.GetPosition(DrawingTarget));
}
```

Ну и при отпускании мыши мы должны добавить последнюю точку, завершить фигуру, завершить режим рисования, и отпустить мышь.

```
void DrawingMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    AddFigurePoint(e.GetPosition(DrawingTarget));
    EndFigure();
    isDrawing = false;
    Mouse.Capture(null);
}
```

Нам осталось реализовать собственно рисующие методы `StartFigure`, `AddFigurePoint` и `EndFigure`. Можно рисовать по-всякому, и наверное, рисование при помощи `Polyline` было бы на две строки проще. Но давайте рисовать при помощи `Path` для разнообразия.

Для начала немного теории. `Path` состоит из множества фигур (`Figure`). У нас будет одна фигура. Каждая фигура, в свою очередь, состоит из множества сегментов (`Segment`). Сегменты бывают разные, но мы возьмём просто линейный сегмент, соединяющий предыдущую точку с новой. Текущую фигуру мы будем запоминать в переменной, чтобы добавлять к ней точки.

```
PathFigure currentFigure;
```

Самый сложный код — `StartFigure`, нам нужно создать новую фигуру и добавить её на `Canvas`.

```
void StartFigure(Point start)
{
    currentFigure = new PathFigure() { StartPoint = start };
    var currentPath =
        new Path()
        {
            Stroke = Brushes.Red,
            StrokeThickness = 3,
            Data = new PathGeometry() { Figures = { currentFigure } }
        };
    DrawingTarget.Children.Add(currentPath);
}
```

Добавление новой точки делается очень просто:

```
void AddFigurePoint(Point point)
{
    currentFigure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(point, isStroked: true));
}
```

Ну и чтобы завершить фигуру, нам практически нечего делать. Можно разве что подчистить за собой:

```
void EndFigure()
{
    currentFigure = null;
}
```

Получаем вот такой результат:

[image: кролики! они заполонили всю планету!]

---

Чтобы делать совсем правильно, вам нужно освоить MVVM и передавать информацию в VM-уровень, например, как это реализовано тут: [Drag & Drop с предпросмотром](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618048/10105).

Comment: спасибо) сейчас буду разбираться с этим)  пока что у меня еще больше вопросов появилось) но начну вначале разбираться) А можно ли в `canvas'e` ограничить область рисования? Например, я вложил в него графический элемент и хочу рисовать только в его области. Можно ли отлавить флаг нахождения или не нахождения курсора в области этого элемента и передавать в свойства `canvas` для рисования?

Comment: @АлександрМустафин: Можно, конечно. Только зачем вам что-то вкладывать в Canvas? Canvas — это и есть область рисования. Хотите область рисования меньше — сделайте Canvas поменьше.

Comment: Мне просто нужно рисовать именно внутри объекта `<lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Column="1" VisualElements="{Binding Visuals}" Name="chart" />` поэтому хочу его вложить в Canvas.