# Рисование линии в inkCanvas

Tags: wpf

Пишу стандартный графический редактор на WPF с возможностью рисования элементарных геометрических фигур (как в Paint). Как на `inkCanvas'e` нарисовать линию между двумя точками, которые определяет пользователь кликами мыши?

Comment: А как пробовали? И почему не просто `Canvas`, а именно `InkCanvas`?

Comment: @Андрей я выбрал `inkCanvas` из-за наличия у него свойства `EditingMode`. Ну и банально он даёт возможность рисования мышью, некоторые другие плюшки. Или в моём случае целесообразнее использовать обычный `Canvas`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/671735/10105

Comment: @VladD там речь идёт об `Canvas`, но возник вопрос: сильно ли отличаются `Canvas` и `inkCanvas`? И много ли кода придётся изменять?

Comment: @Moonlight: Без малейшего понятия, я ни разу не пользовался `InkCanvas`. Попробуйте, расскажете мне потом.