# Перетаскивание картинок с ListBox на Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, drag-n-drop, wpf-canvas

Есть listbox который содержит изображения, и canvas в качестве поля для перетаскивания, объясните мне, как добавить drag and drop  для картинок,чтобы разместить их на canvas и слепить из них одно изображение по нажатию кнопки.[image: окно программы] 
Заполнение listbox:

```
CClothContext db = new CClothContext();
var ClList = db.Clothe.ToList();
foreach (var num in ClList)
{
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Source = byteArrayToImage(num.Cloth_img).Source;
    ClothList.Items.Add(img);
}
```

Comment: Это сложная задача. Посмотрите вот сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/591337/10105 Работы у вас очень много, поздравляю.

Comment: А нет способа без mvvm?

Comment: Есть, но без MVVM сложнее.

Comment: Просто уже нет времени переносить все приложение на mvvm

Comment: Ну, без опыта выполнить это задание _быстро_ всё равно не выйдет. Так что если времени реально нет, бегите от этого задания подальше.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за помощь;)

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так:
xaml code

```
    <Grid AllowDrop="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox_main" Grid.Column="0" PreviewMouseDown="listBox_main_PreviewMouseDown" SelectionMode="Multiple">

                    <Image Source="Resources\1.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" Height="100" Width="100"></Image>
                <Image Source="Resources\2.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" Height="100" Width="100"></Image>
                <Image Source="Resources\3.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" Height="100" Width="100"></Image>
                <Image Source="Resources\4.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" Height="100" Width="100"></Image>
                <Image Source="Resources\5.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" Height="100" Width="100"></Image>
        </ListBox>

        <Canvas AllowDrop="True" Background="Transparent" x:Name="canvas_main" Grid.Column="1" DragEnter="canvas_main_DragEnter" Drop="canvas_main_Drop"
               
         >
            <Image Source="Resources\5.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" Height="100" Width="100"></Image>

        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

Code:

```
    private void canvas_main_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Если пользователь копирует объект перетаскиванием и это список файлов и это не перетаскивание из listBox в него же
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("MyappformatBitmapSource") &&
            (e.AllowedEffects & DragDropEffects.Copy) != 0)
        {
            // Разрешить копирование
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
    }

    private void canvas_main_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Если перетаскивается картинка
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("MyappformatBitmapSource"))
        {
            foreach (BitmapSource bSource in (BitmapSource[])e.Data.GetData("MyappformatBitmapSource"))
            {                    // Показать картинку
                Image new_image = new Image()
                {
                    Source=bSource,
                    Stretch = Stretch.Uniform,
                    Width=100,
                    Height=100
                };
                canvas_main.Children.Add(new_image);
                Canvas.SetLeft(new_image, 100);
                Canvas.SetTop(new_image, 100);
            }
        }
    }

    private void listBox_main_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        // Создать контейнер для хранения данных
        DataObject data = new DataObject();

        if (listBox_main.SelectedItems.Count <= 0)
            return;

        // Положить содержимое выделенной в списке
        BitmapSource[] col = new BitmapSource[listBox_main.SelectedItems.Count];
       
        for(int i=0;i< listBox_main.SelectedItems.Count;i++)
        {
            if(listBox_main.SelectedItems[i] is Image image)
                col[i]=(BitmapSource)image.Source;
        };

        // Добавить признак пользовательского формата в контейнер
        data.SetData("MyappformatBitmapSource",col);

        // НАЧАТЬ перетаскивание программно
        DragDropEffects dde = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
```