# Можно ли создать массив элементов Rectangle?

Tags: wpf

Мне нужно в сетку Grid динамически расположить шесть прямоугольников Rectangle разного цвета.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно, конечно, прописать каждый в отдельности. Но, наверное, есть более подходящий способ для этого?

Потом надо будет к каждому прямоугольнику добавить возможность перетаскивать его копию (мышью).

Для начала можно дать общую информацию, чтобы я смог сориентироваться в каком направлении мне двигаться.

Я что-то подобное уже делал в Windows Forms: создавал массив кнопок, которые можно было перетаскивать (мышью). Но в WPF, как я понимаю, все работает по другому.

Comment: [Как поместить в ячейку Grid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820820/220553), [Как для нужного типа задать нужный вид](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1430956/220553), [Перетаскивание объектов (правда не совсем то, что нужно, но по аналогии сделать можно думаю)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618048/220553).

Comment: EvgeniyZ, спасибо, посмотрю...

Answer (score 0):

Массив прямоугольников создал.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Осталось реализовать перетаскивание.

Вот код кому интересно:

```
    Rectangle[] recArr = new Rectangle[6];

    createRecArr();

    void createRecArr()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            Color color = numToColor(i);
            recArr[i] = new Rectangle();

            mainGrid.Children.Add(recArr[i]);
            Grid.SetColumn(recArr[i], 10 + i);
            Grid.SetRow(recArr[i], 10);
            recArr[i].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        }
    }

    Color numToColor(int vcolor)
    {
        Color colr = new Color();

        switch (vcolor)
        {
            case 0:
                colr =  Colors.White;
                break;
            case 1:
                colr =  Colors.Red;
                break;
            case 2:
                colr =  Colors.Blue;
                break;
            case 3:
                colr =  Colors.Yellow;
                break;
            case 4:
                colr =  Colors.Orange;
                break;
            case 5:
                colr =  Colors.Green;
                break;
        }

        return colr;
    }
```

Можно ли элемент помещенный в ячейку Gridа плавно перетаскивать независимо от сетки или надо по другому реализовывать расположение элементов?