# WPF контейнер для динамического расположения объектов по координатам

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvp

Здравствуйте.

Вопрос в следующем:

Как в WPF реализовать контейнер типа Canvas, в котором можно было бы динамически располагать объекты по координатам.
Желание разграничить model и view, т.е. объекты создаются, удаляются и меняются в model и не знают о view.

Пара примечаний:

1) Далеко не все свойства логического элемента нужны для отрисовки.

2) Желательно, чтобы графический элемент так же не был жёстко привязан к контейнеру, а, например реализовывал какой-либо интерфейс или просто имел необходимые контейнеру свойства.

Вот один из вариантов базы задачи:

**1) Один логический элемент:**

```
public class LogicElement : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void Notify(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    // Coordinates
    private double top;
    public double Top
    {
        get { return top; }
        set { top = value; Notify("Top"); }
    }
    private double left;
    public double Left
    {
        get { return left; }
        set { left = value; Notify("Left"); }
    }

    // Text
    private string caption = string.Format("{0: HH:mm:ss:fff}", DateTime.Now);
    public string Caption
    {
        get { return caption; }
        set { caption = value; Notify("Caption"); }
    }
}
```

**2) Один графический элемент:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfTestCanvasContainer.GraphicElement"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
            <TextBlock Name="TextBlockCaption" Background="LimeGreen" 
                       Text="Caption of logic element here..."/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**3) Контейнер графических элементов:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestCanvasContainer.GraphicWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="GraphicWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="CanvasMain"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: А чем вас сам `Canvas` не устраивает?

Comment: Да устраивает. Просто я не могу придумать, как красиво сшить три предложенные элемента, чтобы реализовать mvvm, при котором модель не знает, что её рисуют.

Comment: Ну вот вам пример: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647/10105