# Как в концепции MVVM динамически добавлять элементы?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Как в концепции MVVM динамически добавлять элементы? 
Необходимо создавать произвольное количество элементов например Border и располагать в произвольном месте окна.

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Динамический список элементов в WPF делается одним способом — через `ItemsControl` .

Если вы хотите располагать элементы не линейно, вам нужно переопределить `ItemsPanel`, например, как это сделано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647/10105):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <!-- это привязка координат контейнера к VM -->
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Position.X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Position.Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- тут описываете, как выглядит ваш элемент -->
            <!-- в вашем случае это Border -->
            <Border ... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```