# WPF добавить несколько изображений

Tags: wpf, изображения

Возник вопрос как в wpf дабавить сразу несколько картинок на рабочее поле, с возможностью изменять их размер и положение, какие элементы управления использовать в качестве рабочего поля, или может кто подскажет библиотеку?

Comment: Ну, а как вы добавляете одно изображение? Несколько точно так же.

Comment: И что означает возможность изменять размер/положение? Изменять программе, или юзеру?

Comment: Идей ноль, даже как добавить одно, чтобы можно было менять его положение и ресайзить с помощью курсора

Comment: А, курсором! Посмотрите сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647/10105