# Синхронизация событий мыши в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, события, мышь

Я хочу, чтобы у меня объекты в Canvas двигались при нажатие мыши и перемещение по горизонтали. Всё получается отлично, кроме того, что если я не двигаю мышь и отпускаю левую кнопку, всё успешно, но если я двигаю мышь и в этот момент отпускаю, бывает не срабатывает `MouseUp` событие. Как можно это исправить? Приоритет событий что ли. Но надо, чтобы все расчеты в событии `MouseMove` заканчивались, если вызывается событие `MouseUp`.

Comment: А почему не приходит MouseUp? Вы небось забыли сделать Capture?

Comment: @VladD Да, не делал, а что это именно? Ну, как я понял, если я в данный момент двигаю мышь и отпускаю кнопку, то у меня не успевает ловить MouseUp т.к. идет просчет по событию MouseMove

Comment: Нет, проблема не в этом. Проблема в том, что если вы не делаете Capture, то при выходе за границы элемента вам перестают доставляться мышиные события, в частности MouseUp. Хороший пример смотрите в ответе @tym32167 и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/745304/10105).

Comment: @VladD а, этот момент у меня был прописал через MouseLeave

Comment: К вам после MouseDown должен прийти либо MouseLeave, либо MouseUp. Если не приходит, вы где-то ошиблись.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не использовать MouseUp. Достаточно в MouseMove проверять наличие нажатия клавиши.

```
    private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
             // Тут ваш код движения.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Гениально, как я до этого сразу не догадался) Буду знать. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4):

Я как то писал законченный пример для перетаскивания элементов на канвасе. У меня перетаскивается по 2 координатам, но вы можете просто удалить изменения по вертикали и оставить только по горизонтали

```
class MyWnd : Window
{       
    public MyWnd()
    {
        var c = new Canvas();
        c.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        var rect = new Rectangle 
                   { 
                     Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), 
                     Width = 20, Height = 20 
                    };
        c.Children.Add(rect);

        this.Content = c;

        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, 0);

        rect.MouseLeftButtonDown+=Handle_MouseDown;
        rect.MouseLeftButtonUp+=Handle_MouseUp;
        rect.MouseMove+=Handle_MouseMove;
    }


    bool isMouseCaptured;
    double mouseVerticalPosition;
    double mouseHorizontalPosition;

    public void Handle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = sender as FrameworkElement;
        mouseVerticalPosition = args.GetPosition(null).Y;
        mouseHorizontalPosition = args.GetPosition(null).X;
        isMouseCaptured = true;
        item.CaptureMouse();
    }

    public void Handle_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (isMouseCaptured)
        {

            // Calculate the current position of the object.
            double deltaV = args.GetPosition(null).Y - mouseVerticalPosition;
            double deltaH = args.GetPosition(null).X - mouseHorizontalPosition;
            double newTop = deltaV + (double)item.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);
            double newLeft = deltaH + (double)item.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);

            // Set new position of object.
            item.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newTop);
            item.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newLeft);

            // Update position global variables.
            mouseVerticalPosition = args.GetPosition(null).Y;
            mouseHorizontalPosition = args.GetPosition(null).X;
        }
    }

    public void Handle_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = sender as FrameworkElement;
        isMouseCaptured = false;
        item.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        mouseVerticalPosition = -1;
        mouseHorizontalPosition = -1;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var wnd = new MyWnd();
    wnd.ShowDialog();
}
```

А по поводу `Capture`, что вам советовали - это у меня в строчке `item.CaptureMouse();`

Comment: Спасибо большое, пригодится мне в будущем. Еще 1 вопрос, например, у меня в Canvas'e очень много прямоугольников. Как можно реализовать то, чтобы при наведение на любой из прямоугольник в данном Canvas'e, у меня показывались его координаты в ToolTip? MouseEnter реализует заход именно в поле Canvas, но нужно отследить, на какой именно объект попал курсор мыши и если это один из многих прямоугольников, мы выводим рядом с мышью окошко с его координатами.

Comment: А, я просто для каждого прямоугольника добавляю ToolTip. Всё оказывается просто)

Comment: Так подпишитесь на `MouseEnter` для прямоугольника. Я [делал подобное](http://tym32167.blogspot.com/2011/12/silverlight.html) в виде `Behavior` - смотрите `HoverBehavior<T>`

Comment: Я вас понял, если что, буду таким образом записывать, спасибо)