# Как перемещать Control в wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse-event

Требуется по удержанию кнопки мыши начать премещать объект, при отпускании перестать премещать и оставить на новой позиции.

Comment: [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/748981/179763)?

Comment: Или [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591337/drag-drop-с-предпросмотром)