# Реализация инструмента выделения

Tags: c#, wpf

Как на wpf реализовать выделение и перемещение выбранной области на канвасе, и если есть несколько вариантов - какой быстрее

Спасибо

Comment: Сами что то пытались сделать? [Или поискать](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148503/Simple-Drag-Selection-in-WPF)? Если пытались, то что пытались и какой результат попыток?

Comment: Думала в выделенной облачти считать пиксели и потом перемещать их, не спец в этом, но куда их нужно записать, дабы не терять в производительности и не сдвигать каждый пиксель вручную

Comment: Нашла пару ссылок на английском overflow, но ответа нет

Comment: не понял про пиксели. Юзер нажал кнопку мышки в точке 1, отпустил в точке 2, точки 1 и 2 образуют прямоугольник, всё, что внутри пямоугольника, подлежит выделению

Comment: Это да, а как работает перемещение?

Comment: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618048/179763), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/748981/179763)?