# WPF C#. Изменение объектов DrawingVisual на поле Canvas

Tags: c#

Добавляю объекты DrawingVisual на canvas, такие как прямоугольник, линия, элипс. При перемещении объекта мышкой происходит такая штука: при первом клике и перетаскивании визуально объект перемещается, при последующих кликах объект возращается в то место куда был добавлен и перемещение идет относительно этой позиции, хотя курсор может находиться на другой стороне холста.

Предполагаю, что объект надо перерисовать вызвав RenderOpen(). Но тут трудность как определить какой метод вызывать, для отрисовки прямоугольника, линии, или другой фигуры?
Подскажите варианты решения данной проблемы.

Comment: Может вы перетаскивание делаете как то не так? Я когда про писал [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/748981/179763) дял перетаскивания по канвасу, попробуйте, может сработает.

Comment: Да все так делаю. Если работать с одним  видом фигур, то вызвав RenderOpen() и перерисовав фигуру все работает отлично. А если несколько различных фигур и все имеют один тип, то как быть?!

Comment: Все что нашел в интернете по перетаскиванию DrawingVisual показано на примере одного вида фигур, например квадрат.  Как будто дальше никто не заморачивался

Comment: ну вы кода никакого не привели, так что вам никто не скажет, что вы делате не так.