# Что требуется для минимального каркаса заготовка MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Делаю заготовку проекта C# WPF,  универсальную так сказать чтобы потом можно было просто копировать все папку для нового проекта ,
сделал так:
- создал папки и классы , переместил MainWindow.xaml, получилось вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

поправил App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="ШаблонMVVM.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ШаблонMVVM"
StartupUri="View\MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

дописал две строчки в MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ШаблонMVVM.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ШаблонMVVM"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ШаблонMVVM.ViewModel"
DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, ElementName=MainWindowInstance}">
 <Grid>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

в коде окна ни чего не трогал

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace ШаблонMVVM
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

ClassModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ШаблонMVVM.Model
{
    class ClassModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

ClassViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ШаблонMVVM.ViewModel
{
    class ClassViewModel
    {

    }
}
```

Подскажите 
1) достаточно ли этого чтобы назвать это каркас проекта C#WPFMVVM ?
2) если нет то что нужно добавить и в какой модуль?

каркас хочу приготовить как бы универсальный

Comment: Я бы сразу добавил точку объединения View и ViewModel. Сейчас у вас они нигде не связываются. Я обычно это делаю в App.cs, где удалю StartupURI и в событии Startup создаю окно с DataContext.

Comment: реализации ICommand не хватает)

Comment: `DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, ElementName=MainWindowInstance}"` – это что такое? Не будет же работать. По сути, в самом минимальном варианте, вам нужно: а) реализация INPC, б) реализация ICommand, в) корневое место, где создается VM, окно и устанавливается ему в DataContext ссылка на эту VM

Comment: DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, ElementName=MainWindowInstance}
 -  я  думал это и есть точка объединения View и ViewModel

Comment: реализации ICommand не хватает) – Gardes      -   а  как добавить ,  это класс ?  отдельный  файл создавать ? ,  что  в него писать

Comment: Андрей NOP -  подскажите пожалуста конкретно схему , т.е. какие файлы и что в них написать ,

Comment: [(1)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/218063) [(2)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647/218063) Там есть и INPC и ICommand в том числе

Comment: Андрей NOP  - большое спасибо , но  эти ссылки я уже давно изучил ,  у меня другой случай мне надо шаблон скилет так сказать с которого можно было бы начать как с чистого листа , т.е. загатовка  ,  и что самое главное в Ваших ссылках  в какие файлы что вписыввать, подскажите пожалуста , вот три файла что в них конкретно вписать что бы получился типа стартового шаблона

Comment: Вся проблема в том что везде расписуют как бы можно было сделать как хорошо использовать тот или иной фрейм ворк и так далее , и во всех видео курсах (вооще сопли детсада)  на ютубе допускают ошибки опечатки оговорки не досказы и так далее и не один проект не работает без пляски с бубном ,  а нужен просто каркас с чего начать , конкретно (без соплей фреймворков) в таком то файле тото

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для начала мой вам совет, забудьте про русские названия переменных, проектов и др. Это не правильно (`namespace ШаблонMVVM.Model`)!

По поводу MVVM, что нам нужно знать основное? Ну для начала для чего вообще он используется. А используется он для разделения всего и вся на слои:

- **Model** - Ваши данные (база, что то подгружаемое с сайта или др. источник данных).
- **View** - То, что видит пользователь (интерфейс, всякие оповещения и др. вещи).
- **ViewModel** - Некий связывающий слой, который помогает "собрать" все одно целое, тут мы описываем логику для View, берем данные из Model и другие полезности.

Тут вам стоит запомнить еще пару вещей:

1. Из Model и ViewModel вы не как не должны взаимодействовать с данными во View слое (то есть `MyTextBox1.Text = "Hello!"` в MVVM не уместно!). View должна знать только то, что в некой ViewModel может быть некое свойство `Text` из которого ей следует брать текст для Control'a. Данного свойства может вовсе не быть (удален, переименован), View на это будет грубо говоря все равно, нечего не упадет и все будет грамотно работать (за исключением естественно данного значения). Другими словами наш интерфейс не как не зависит от кода, что позволяет к примеру разрабатывать двумя разными командами интерфейс и код по отдельности, либо изменить интерфейс убрав из него не нужные элементы (не трогая при этом код).  В этом и суть разделения всего по слоям.
2. Каждая Model/ViewModel должна отвечать за свое, что то одно. Грубый пример: К примеру у нас есть студент который имеет некие книги, студент - это некая ViewModel со своим набором данных (имя, фамилия, список книг, команды (прочитать, отдать) и др информация, связанная только с ним), книга это уже другой объект, которая тоже должна иметь все, что связанно именно с ней (ну например название, автор, дата выпуска, где находится). То есть у вас не должно быть такое, что за функционал книги отвечает ViewModel студента или наоборот!

Хорошо, давайте теперь напишем простенькое приложение:

1. Создаем 3 папки Model, ViewModel и View.
2. В View переносим MainWindow (со всеми его потрохами, не забываем поменять все пути).
3. Создадим 3 класса в директории ViewModel:

   1. **BaseVM** - некий класс, который будет реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Что это вообще и для чего нужно? К примеру мы привязали некое свойство скажем к TextBox, при изменений данного свойства из кода интерфейс не будет знать об этом и не обновит данные. Для именно этого оповещения и существует INPC. Реализаций данного класса в интернете уйма, я лично использую этот:

      ```
      public class BaseVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
      {
          public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

          protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
          {
              if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
                  return false;

              field = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
              return true;
          }

          protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
          {
              PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
          }
      }
      ```
   2. **RelayCommand** - Так, как наша View должна быть независима от ViewModel мы не можем просто так использовать Click и другие события (хотя в некоторых случаях это считается приемлемым). Вот на помощь к нам приходят команды, мы создаем свойство данной команды и привязываемся и даже если его нет - наша программа не упадет и будет работать как надо. Как и VM, в интернете реализаций уйма, самая распространенная я думаю [описана на данном сайте](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.3.php), но я опять возьму другой вариант:

      ```
      public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
      {
          private Action<T> action;
          public RelayCommand(Action<T> action) => this.action = action;
          public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
          #pragma warning disable CS0067
          public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
          #pragma warning restore CS0067
          public void Execute(object parameter) => action((T)parameter);
      }

      public class RelayCommand : ICommand
      {
          private Action action;
          public RelayCommand(Action action) => this.action = action;
          public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
          #pragma warning disable CS0067
          public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
          #pragma warning restore CS0067
          public void Execute(object parameter) => action();
      }
      ```
   3. **MainViewModel** - Это наша основная VM. Код описывать не буду, пока просто создадим пустой класс.
4. Теперь давайте зададим DataContext. Честно, сам до конца не понял как правильней, один хороший человек мне помнится по рукам бил за указания DataContext в XAML разметке, а с недавних пор я прочитал и вовсе, что его лучше задавать на уровень выше (в App). По этому я здесь буду использовать именно App (кто не согласен, дайте знать).

   1. Удаляем в App.xaml `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` и подписывемся там же на Startup событие.
   2. Вынесем за пределы метода переменную нашего окна (вдруг потом понадобится), пишем `private MainWindow MainWindow;`.
   3. В созданном студией методе (подпись на Startup событие) нам надо инициализировать нашу MainViewModel и задать ее окну, ну и естественно показать его:

      ```
      private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
      {
          var mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
          MainWindow = new MainWindow { DataContext = mainViewModel };
          MainWindow.Show();
      }
      ```

На этом можно сказать, что "стартовый" шаблон у нас создан, осталось написать только логику.

---

Простейший пример того, как с этим взаимодействовать:

1. Создадим в Model некую модель, которая будет отдавать данные. Назовем ее Student.

   ```
   public class Student
   {
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }

       public Student[] GetStudents()
       {
           var result = new[]
           {
                   new Student{FirstName = "Маша", LastName = "Иванова"},
                   new Student{FirstName = "Витя", LastName = "Егоров"},
                   new Student{FirstName = "Женя", LastName = "Петров"}
           };

           return result;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Далее нам понадобится ViewModel нашего студента, создадим, в ней реализуем необходимую логику для студента:

   ```
   public class StudentViewModel : BaseVM
   {
       public StudentViewModel(string firstName, string lastName)
       {
           this.firstName = firstName;
           this.lastName = lastName;
           RenameCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(Rename);
       }

       private string firstName;
       public string FirstName
       {
           get => firstName;
           set => Set(ref firstName, value);
       }

       private string lastName;
       public string LastName
       {
           get => lastName;
           set => Set(ref lastName, value);
       }

       public ICommand RenameCommand { get; set; }

       private void Rename(string name)
       {
           FirstName = name;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Объединим все это в MainViewModel:

   ```
   public class MainViewModel
   {
       public ObservableCollection<StudentViewModel> Students { get; set; }
       private Student StudentData;

       public MainViewModel()
       {
           StudentData = new Student();
           Students = new ObservableCollection<StudentViewModel>();
           LoadData();
       }

       private void LoadData()
       {
           foreach (var student in StudentData.GetStudents())
               Students.Add(new StudentViewModel(student.FirstName, student.LastName));
       }
   }
   ```
4. Осталось написать простейшую View:

   ```
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Grid Margin="5">
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                   <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                   <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Name="changeText" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                   <Button Grid.Column="3" Content="Изменить" Command="{Binding RenameCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=changeText, Path=Text}"/>
               </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
   ```

Вот собственно и все, запускаем и проверяем:

[image: Result]

Тут конечно свои нюансы, могут быть у меня не точности, но основную суть я думаю вы поймете.
Также (как правильно подметил @tym32167), некий универсальный шаблон вам все же не сделать, у каждого проекта есть свои нюансы, тонкости. В некоторых проектах такой подход будет не уместен (где то может лучше будет использовать сторонние фреймворки ([MVVM Light](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight);[Caliburn.Micro](https://caliburnmicro.com);[Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism)) для облегчения всего этого, а где то и этого будет достаточно), все зависит от целей и проекта, но для понимания того, как все это работает, я думаю, моего ответа вам будет вполне достаточно.
Удачи в изучении!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79992/discussion-on-answer-by-evgeniyz------).

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно и этого. В Вашем шаблоне View ничего не знает о Model, как и Model ничего не знает о View. При этом, View что-то знает о ViewModel, ViewModel что-то знает о Model, но не наоборот. Фактически - всё по канонам MVVM.

Единственное - можно выделить отдельный класс по типу "BaseViewModel", который бы наследовали все классы ViewModel. А в нём реализовать интерфейс INPC. Но это не жесткое требование, так, рекомендация