# Автоматический расчет в столбце Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

У меня есть класс Post_zakaz

```
public class Post_zakaz
{
    public Post_zakaz(int kod_t, string nazv_t, int kod_r, string nazv_r, double kol, double cena_ed)
    {
        this.kod_t = kod_t;
        this.nazv_t = nazv_t;
        this.kod_r = kod_r;
        this.nazv_r = nazv_r;
        this.kol = kol;
        this.cena_ed = cena_ed;
        this.obsh = kol * cena_ed;
    }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public int kod_t { get; set; }
    public string nazv_t { get; set; }
    public int kod_r { get; set; }
    public string nazv_r { get; set; }
    public double kol { get; set; }
    public double cena_ed { get; set; }
    public double obsh { get; set; }
}
```

Есть переменная для хранения значений, полученных из базы:

```
public static ObservableCollection<Post_zakaz> postzakazis = new ObservableCollection<Post_zakaz>();
```

Далее есть DataGrid с привязкой к коллекции:

```
<DataGrid Name="Grid" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="№"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Товар" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=nazv_t}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Разновидность" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=nazv_r}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Количество" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=kol}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цена за ед" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=cena_ed}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Общая сумма" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=obsh}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

В столбце "Общая сумма" при изменении одного из  полей "Количество" или "Цена за ед" должен происходить перерасчет "Общей суммы". Сейчас она рассчитывается только при заполнении, т.к. поле *obsh* из класса *Post_zakaz* присваивается один раз.

Я так поняла, что нужно реализовывать INotifyPropertyChanged для класса? Пока я от этого далека, но пытаюсь понять.

**Как правильно реализовать данную идею?**
Возможно как-то можно изменять столбец в самом DataGrid?

Comment: Я вам советую почитать например [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852526/220553), я в нем подробно постарался расписать как сделать проект по правилам MVVM. Если вы поймете его, то решение данной задачи у вас труда не составит.

Comment: Я, вроде, реализовала интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged. Теперь осталось найти событие в DataGrid, которое реагирует на изменение ячейки.

Comment: Вы не должны работать с `DataGrid`. Забудьте вообще про интерфейс, его задача только отобразить, не более. Работайте непосредственно с классом `Post_zakaz`, это его задача посчитать сумму и задать ее в нужное свойство.

Comment: Сейчас он у меня подсчитывает итоговую стоимость. Я так поняла мне нужно привязать поле, которое подсчитывает стоимость в разметке с помощью Binding?

Comment: Оно же у вас уже привязано `Header="Общая сумма" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=obsh}"`, вам остается лишь обновить ему значение и чтобы данные обновились в View, реализовать этому свойству INPC

Comment: Мне понадобился час, чтобы понять как это работает :-). Я ведь сначала всё-таки искала и реализовала присваивание значения из выбранной ячейки пока не поняла, что оно и так присваивается автоматически.... фэйлспам....

Comment: Поймите одну простейшую вещь. Если вы делаете привязки, то интерфейс для вас становиться лишь средством отображения, как дисплей у компьютера, который ничего не высчитывает, а лишь отображает. Разрабатывайте приложение так, будто у вас консольный проект, у которого вовсе нет UI. В вашем случае вы просто задаете `obsh` (кстати, очень странные названия) то значение, которое вам надо, и все, интерфейс не трогаете, нечего другого не трогаете. Про другие ваши ошибки я говорить сейчас не буду, это я думаю вы сами поймете со временем. Сейчас главное поймите саму суть WPF.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, что я сделала:

Реализовала интерфейс INPC (пока не полностью понимая как он работает. Просто зная, что он делает)

```
public class Post_zakaz : INotifyPropertyChanged // "подключаем" интерфейс
{
    public Post_zakaz(int kod_t, string nazv_t, int kod_r, string nazv_r, double kol, double cena_ed)
    {
        this.kod_t = kod_t;
        this.nazv_t = nazv_t;
        this.kod_r = kod_r;
        this.nazv_r = nazv_r;
        this.kol = kol;
        this.cena_ed = cena_ed;
        this.obsh = kol * cena_ed;
    }

    private int kod_t, kod_r;
    private string nazv_t, nazv_r;
    public double kol, cena_ed, obsh;
    public int Kod_t 
    { get { return kod_t; } set { kod_t = value; OnPropertyChanged() /* Этот метод указывает на то, какое свойство должно измениться. Если он пустой, то ничего не меняет*/; } }
    public string Nazv_t
    { get { return nazv_t; } set { nazv_t = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    public int Kod_r
    { get { return kod_r; } set { kod_r = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    public string Nazv_r
    { get { return nazv_r; } set { nazv_r = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    public double Kol
    { get { return kol; } set { kol = value; OnPropertyChanged("Obsh") /*В данном случае при установке значения этот метод оповещает свойство "Obsh" что ему пора поменять значение (как я поняла, повторно вызвать set обновляемого свойства) */; } }
    public double Cena_ed
    { get { return cena_ed; } set { cena_ed = value; OnPropertyChanged("Obsh"); } }
    public double Obsh
    { get { return kol * cena_ed; } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) //если при вызове метода есть параметр
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); //тут что-то пока непонятное для меня
        }
    }
```

Ну и впринципе всё! Далее, если соответствующая коллекция привязана к DataGrid, то при изменении ячейки происходит изменение соответствующего свойства в строке коллекции.

**Спасибо большое людям, которые откликаются! Ваши ответы помогают понимать это всё и учиться новому!**

Comment: Советую вынести INPC в отдельный класс и наследоваться от него там, где он нужен, помните, что программисты ленивые люди и повторно писать один и тот же код... сами понимаете) Также смотрите, INPC обновляет интерфейс тогда, когда свойство изменило значение. Если в UI например в текстовом поле вы пропишете новое значение, то оно будет изменено у свойства, если же вы сделаете наоборот и измените свойство программно, то оно не будет отображать новое значение в UI. У вас, как я понял, таких свойств 3 и только они должны вызывать INPC. Я чуть подправил [ваш класс](https://pastebin.com/5q6shVrV).

Comment: Ого! Хорошее объяснение! Спасибо!