# Привязать уже сфомированный List к ListView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Подскажите пожалуйста, как привязать коллекцию, которая у меня сформирована в другом классе, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку заполнился ListView, не используя в основном коде программы свойство ItemSource, то есть чтобы через привязку это делалось автоматически, или какие вообще пути решения есть. Везде по-разному пишут. Хотелось точно понять как это делать. Спасибо!

P.S. сейчас ListView заполняется, но используется при этом в коде свойство ItemSource

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
        <Button x:Name="Go" Content="Поехали" Height="25" Margin="5" Click="Go_Click"/>
        <ListView  Margin="5" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Stolb1" Width="100"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Код в основной части:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> mylist { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListUp listUp = new ListUp();
        ListView.ItemsSource = listUp.Numbers;
    }
    private class ListUp : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public List<string> Numbers = new List<string> {"1", "2","3" };

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Везде по разному пишут наверно потому, что у каждого свой подход?) Все зависит от того, что вы конкретно хотите, правильней будет - научиться работать по правилам MVVM, этот подход полностью весь завязан на привязках. Ваш подход тоже уместен в каком-то роде, но он не масштабируем и трудно поддерживаем, если кода становиться много. Так что давайте больше конкретики что вы хотите, ибо выложили рабочий код и...?

Comment: Понял, можете тогда подсказать пожалуйста, как на моем примере сделать масштабируемый код? Что нужно исправить? Дальше, насколько я понял, чтобы, например мне сделать то ж самое с 2-мя и более столбцами, мне нужно уже делать коллекцию класса получается, в котором будут только переменные, через которые получаю доступ к основной коллекции? 
Просто чем больше смотришь, тем больше путаницы возникает.
Внизу ответили, но пока это сложно для меня и не понятно, хотелось бы максимально упрощенно на моем примере. Спасибо)

Comment: Я однажды писал [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852526/220553) ответ, в нем постарался сделать минимально и просто для понимания. Посмотрите, может вам будет проще разобраться там. Поймите главное основную суть, что вы не должны хранить данные в контролах, вы делите все на удобные слои, которые отвечают за что-то свое. По поводу вашего примера, ответ ниже является минимальным, куда же еще проще?) Постарайтесь сами написать такое, поверьте, это легко!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У контролов есть свойство `DataContext` все биндинги работают относительно того объекта, на который этот `DataContext` указывает.

С точки зрения подхода **MVVM** ваша задача решается так:

1) Создайте класс `MainViewModel`, он будет содержать свойства для биндингов главного окна.

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _myList;

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList
    {
        get => _myList;
        set
        {
            _myList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

2) Подключите его к окну, самый простой (но не лучший) способ - сделать это в конструкторе класса окна:

```csharp
private MainViewModel VM;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    VM = new MainViewModel();
    this.DataContext = VM;
}
```

К свойствам VM из класса окна можно обращаться например вот так:

```csharp
string str = VM.MyList[0];
```

3) Задайте привязку в xaml

```xaml
<ListView Margin="5" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
```

Ну и (чтобы меня тут не побили другие читатели) стоит учитывать, что MVVM - это когда в классе окна или контрола работа с данными не производится. У меня даже в больших проектах в классе `MainWindow` пусто. Даже ни одного обработчика событий. Взаимодействие интерфейса и кода происходит только через биндинги, и никак иначе. Вам просто будет без надобности обращаться к контролам явно, так как они сами будут себя обновлять через биндинги.

---

Что же делать, когда нажата кнопка в **MVVM**, если не использовать обработчики события? Использовать команды!

Вот класс, позволяющий удобно использовать команды, просто положите его в проект (очень давно взял его [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic)).

```csharp
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

А использовать его можно, добавив в `MainViewModel` вот такой код

```csharp
private ICommand _myCommand;

public ICommand MyCommand => _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Элемент 1", "Элемент 2", "Элемент 3" };
    MyList.Add("Элемент 4");
}));
```

В разметке тоже ничего сложного

```xaml
<Button Content="Поехали" Height="25" Margin="5" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

Comment: В данном примере бесполезен INPC, ибо коллекции (особенно `ObservableCollection`) в основном делают "статичными" (инициализация только раз) и как по мне, лучше найти изменения и их применить, нежели инициализировать по новой коллекцию. Повторная инициализация например, вроде как, сбросит выделение с элемента например того же привязанного `ListBox`. Да и `ObservableCollection`, она создана для того, чтобы оповестить об изменениях внутри себя, зачем она, если изменения будут через повторную инициализацию?) Тогда уж `List<>` использовать, но это уже от задачи зависит.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Верно, но что если разработчик вдруг захочет в рантайме поменять коллекцию на другую? Я умышленно реализовал INPC, это не должно навредить. К тому же в исходном вопросе я увидел попытку что-то сделать с INPC, заодно и показал, как.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а вот и пригодилось INPC в комманде, дописал ответ :)

Comment: Ну, мое отношение к этому я написал выше) Я считаю бессмысленным заново инициализировать коллекцию, которая оповещает о своих внутренних изменениях. Я обычно как делаю - пришли данные с сервера, я их получил в формате `SomeClass[]`, сравнил этот массив с коллекцией и удалил то, что надо из нее и добавил то, что надо в нее, все, у меня идентична коллекция и без повторной инициализации. Если же не нужно следить за изменениями в коллекции, то сойдет простой массив, ну или `List<>`, которые просто содержат объект. Сейчас вот у вас `ObservableCollection<>`, зачем она, если вы не делаете `.Add()`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ теперь делаю. :) Вы всё правильно говорите, про необходимое и достаточное, прямо как я своей команде программистов, когда работаю. Но если я здесь вывалю весь SOLID на человека, задавшего вопрос, то он просто не осилит дочитать всю эту нудятину до конца. Дайте людям возможность пробовать и разбираться, не ограничивайте их рамками Best Practices. Позвольте ошибаться и направляйте. (хотя, я иногда сам не против, если бы за баги ввели административную, а за быдлокод - уголовную отсветственность).

Comment: Я вам лишь сказал свое мнение, что лишь считаю подобную реализацию в вашем примере "неуместной" и лишней что-ли, вы ведь сами говорите "Он не осилит", также я к этому добавлю "Человек возьмет это за эталон и начнет бездумно применять это везде". Я лично не раз видел, где люди бездумно использовали INPC на все подряд. В своем первом комментарии я лишь дополнил ваш ответ, что бы человек (если захочет), понял, что это лучше так не делать и для чего нужны INPC и `ObservableCollection`. К вам претензий нет, лайк уже поставил, лишь дополняю, не более..

Comment: @AntoniBond слева от ответа есть галочка. Пожалуйста используйте её, если мой ответ вас устраивает. Или задайте дополнительный вопрос здесь в комментарии.