# Не заполняется DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Пишу на WPF.
Вот мой код:

```
public void OpenTable(string TableName)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM [{ TableName }]", conn);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        dataGrid.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
        int fh = 0;
        foreach (var el in dataGrid.Columns)
        {
            StackPanel panel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center };
            panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = el.Header.ToString() });
            Button Filter = new Button { Width = 10, Height = 10, Margin = new Thickness(3, 3, 0, 0), VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, BorderBrush = null, Background = null };
            //Filter.Click += Filter_Click;
            Filter.Name = "a" + fh.ToString();
            Filter.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Image/filter.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) };
            panel.Children.Add(Filter);
            el.Header = panel;
            fh++;
            //ISCheced.Add(new List<bool>());
        }
        dataGrid.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;//ошибка: Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции.
        try
        {
            GridContent.Children.Add(dataGrid);
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Смотрела `DataTable` заполнен.
А `DataGrid` никак.
Мой `DataGrid`:

```
DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid { 
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 50, 2, 2), 
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch, 
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch 
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt;`

Comment: @aepot Пробовала неработает.

Comment: @aepot Искала в интернете предложили с DataContext, но как видите не работает.

Comment: `DataContext` это для привязок `Binding`, когда в xaml пишете `ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}"`, то `Binding` ищет `MyData` там, куда указывает `DataContext`. За источник данных отвечает именно `ItemsSource`. Примеров в сети немеряно: быть может [этот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14943273/12888024) решит вашу проблему?

Comment: @aepot Я пробовала через ItemSource, аналогичная ситуация.

Comment: Смотрите ссылку что я дал выше

Comment: @aepot попробовала неработает

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115342/373567) еще я игрался с `DataTable`.

Comment: @aepot а может быть проблема в том что  я создаю Datagrid в c#?

Comment: Возможно. Пример по ссылке последний смотрите. Я там вообще с контролами в C# не работаю, так как это очень неудобно делать в WPF. Создайте пустой проект, перенесите тот пример в проект. И посмотрите, как оно работает. Тем путем, которым пошли вы, я не хожу, для меня это сложно. Именно поэтому, я не до конца понимаю, как и что у вас там работает, что и где создается.

Comment: @aepot посмотрела

Comment: Вот [еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1109976/373567), как работать с коллекциями в WPF. `ListBox`/`ListView`/`ItemsControl` вам помогут.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо.

Comment: @aepot Попробовала создать через XAML DataGrid, сработало. Не знаете почему на работало когда создавала через c#?

Comment: Когда вы создаете `DataGrid` в C#, вам наверное надо его в коллекцию контролов окна или в `Grid` добавлять? Иначе как окно узнает, что вы там где-то `DataGrid` создали, верно? Но история это не простая, примерно [вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1393272/12888024) оно может работать. Я все же предпочитаю работать с данными и полезным кодом, а WPF сам для меня создает контролы, в нужных местах, в нужном количетсве, и сам их обновляет.