# Создать собственное событие для UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol, dependencyproperty

У меня, например, есть UserControl, который является шаблоном для отображения студента в списке. Можно абстрагироваться от его содержимого.

Я хочу создать для него событие Click, подобно кнопке, которая берет обработчик события из класса вызвавшего его (например, window). Возможно ли создать такое событие (по подобию DependencyProoerty)? Чтобы была возможность просто передать метод в разметке (опять же подобно событию click у button). Ну или другие события (при наведении мыши на usercontrol и т.п.)

*Нашла ещё один способ - поменять Объявление UserControl в Xaml и изменить наследование на Button.

Comment: А как насчет того что бы контрол просто обернуть в кнопку? В таком случае событие онклик будет уже создано и ничего дописывать не прийдется

Comment: Вообще в WPF не используют обработчики события `Click`. В WPF используют команды, и вам стоит с ними познакомиться. Команды работотают на основе привязки данных, то есть как любое другое зависимое свойство контрола. Вот [пример использования команд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1109976/373567). Кладете кнопку в `ControlTemplate`, и через `TemplateBinding` привязываете команду и ее параметр в юзерконтролу. Далее в основной разметке все делаете с юзерконтролом так же как с обычной кнопкой.

Comment: Даже если делать команды, они всё равно привязываются через разметку как свойство зависимостей.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый простой вариант думаю будет такой:

Допустим у нас есть некий `UserControl`, который является оберткой над `Button` и нам надо от него пробросить "органы управления" наружу. Делаем нужные `DependencyProperty`, я сделаю всего два:

1. `Text` - Будет отвечать за написанный текст на кнопке.
2. `Command` - Отвечает за клик по этой кнопке.

Получаем в итоге такое:

```
public string Text
{
    get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
    set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default));


public ICommand Command
{
    get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
    set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default));
```

В XAML будет просто:

```
<UserControl ...
             Name="uc">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=uc}" Command="{Binding Command, ElementName=uc}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Собственно все, мы пробросили два свойства и теперь смело можем их использовать:

```
<local:UserControl1 Text="Привет мир!" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
```

Если нам все же нужны именно события (а все события в WPF заменяются без проблем на комманды и не ясно зачем это может понадобиться), то для таких целей существует [маршрутизация событий](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/6.php). Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent ButtonClickEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ButtonClick", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(UserControl1));

public event RoutedEventHandler ButtonClick
{
    add => AddHandler(ButtonClickEvent, value);
    remove => RemoveHandler(ButtonClickEvent, value);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonClickEvent));
```

Сама кнопка в XAML контрола будет такой:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=uc}" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

Теперь наш контрол пробрасывает событие наружу, и мы смело можем его использовать, как и раньше любое другое событие:

```
<local:UserControl1 Text="Привет мир!" ButtonClick="UserControl1_ButtonClick" />
```

Обработчик события

```
private void UserControl1_ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => Debug.WriteLine("Клик по кнопке");
```

Вот так довольно просто мы можем манипулировать событиями контрола, а сами события, в большинстве случаев, достаточно тех, что есть у стандартных объектов, допустим нам нужен клик - оборачиваем, например `<Border>` или что-либо другое в `<Button>`, убираем у него весь стиль (делаем прозрачный, без бордюров и др.) и все, у нас готов элемент, который обрабатывает клики.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Но всё же, можно создать такие события самостоятельно?

Comment: @AB Ну события-то вы создать можете, это простые `event`, но вам так или иначе надо будет отлавливать стандартные события, которые произошли при клике мышью, ее наведения и так далее, а тут я думаю вы уже догадались, что это бессмысленное, ибо идет дублирование того, что уже есть, ибо зачем вам изобретать свой "клик", если он уже есть например в `Button` и намного проще и надежней будет этот `Button` изменить под свои нужды. А если у вас идут события по типу "Возраст человек больше допустимого", то это уже задача ведь не UI.

Comment: @AB Вот давайте разберем допустим клик, он нам нужен на контроле, который не имеет события `Click` (допустим `Grid`), как нам обработать его там? Да просто, берем события мыши (которое есть у всех контролов) и на их основе делаем проверку на клик, допусти через `MouseLeftButtonDown` мы запоминаем, что был произведен клик на контрол, а через `MouseLeftButtonUp` проверяем где именно была отжата кнопка и если она на контроле, то это будет полноценный клик, который вызывает наше кастомное событие и делает нужную логику. Еще не забываем, что у `Button` есть состояния клика (зажата, наведена и др.).

Comment: @AB Выше простое событие клика, будет некий наш "кастом", но зачем нам это все изобретать, если опять же, все это есть в `Button`? Или возьмем, например другое событие, допустим есть свой UC, который кастомизирует `ProgressBar`, нам надо сделать событие, которое покажет на 100% оно заполнилось или нет. Подписываемся на `ValueChanged` и каждое изменение сверяем со свойством `Maximum`, если 100%, то вызываем наше кастомное событие, вроде все ок, но... Следить за тем, заполнилось оно на 100% или нет ведь не задача UI, а задача того, кто устанавливаем ему `Value`, UI должен лишь отобразить.

Comment: Спасибо, как всегда помогаете!!!

Comment: Почему кстати используете обычную разметку, а не `ControlTemplate`? Там бы `x:Name` не понадобился. Я про удобство использования в MVVM.

Comment: @aepot Наверно для простоты, ибо тут достаточно одной строки кнопки, но может потеряться понятие того, что это кусок кода из UC, поэтому я и обозначил его так. Ведь если я сейчас нагружу это все еще и шаблонами, то ведь получим много лишнего, того, что не относиться к вопросу.