# WPF(MVVM) почему люди которые создают Controll, делают событие не для паттерна MVVM dependency property?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, события, usercontrol

Допустим есть у меня контрол

`paz:ZoomBorder`

И у него есть событие  `ZoomChanged=""` и это событие не **dependency property**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И теперь вопрос **почему все делают такие контроллы?**

И если я хочу при вызове события `ZoomChanged` обрабатывать его в ViewModel, как мне это сделать?

И еще один вопрос. Также есть допустим `TextBox` и у него есть разные событие такие как:
`Tapped`, `DoubleTapped`, `PointerEnter`  ....

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как же мне их обрабатывать в ViewModel когда они вызываются?

Comment: Если речь про подписку, то можно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/917223/220553), а если речь про создание своих событий, то [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1216249/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ
То есть, для подписки textbox на событие DoubleTapped что бы оно обработалось в ViewModel. Нужно использовать  <i:Interaction.Triggers> + RelayCommand?

Comment: Типа того, да. По правилам MVVM у вас должны быть мало связанные друг с другом слои, где View слой вообще не должен знать про другие слои, Model также, независимый, а ViewModel общается только с M слоем (и то лучше на основе абстракции). Для того, чтобы View был независимым, есть такая штука как привязки, ну а за всякие действия в сфере привязок отвечают команды (например, не `<Button Click="обработчик">`, а `<Button Command = "{Binding ClickCommand}">`).  Сами события в XAML могут читать триггеры, вот решение выше это и есть триггеры + команды на события.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Понял короче говоря делаю trigger в xaml на команду , юзаю бинд к ViewModel на команду, а в ViewModel команда сделана с RelayCommand, что б получить object который вызвал команду. Спасибо.

Comment: `что б получить object` - тут поищите реализации поудачней команд, их в интернете полно. К примеру я часто использую такую реализацию, как в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852526/220553) ответе, она имеет не весь функционал, но если нужны чисто клики, то почему бы и нет, сразу в нужный тип конвертирует, вам лишь указать его как `command = new RelayCommand<тип>(метод);` и создать метод сразу с нужным типом `private метод (тип value){ ... }`. Более полные команды также легко найти. А то `object` это прям брр)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я понял. Спасибо буду использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> И если я хочу при вызове события ZoomChanged обрабатывать его в ViewModel , как мне это сделать?

> И еще один вопрос. Также есть допустим TextBox и у него есть разные событие такие как: Tapped, DoubleTapped, PointerEnter, как же мне их обрабатывать в ViewModel когда они вызываются?

Не нужно так делать. События View должны обрабатываться внутри View (например - триггеры в `xaml` или же подписка на события контрола внутри окна), а не внутри ViewModel. Хоть и ViewModel является связующим звеном между доменной логикой и представлением, но оно ничего не должно знать об окне где его используют. **Все, что находится в окне - делается внутри окна и нигде больше**. События, цвета, шрифты и то что вы видите человеческим глазом - всё это часть представления которое меняется по щелчку пальцев и будет изменяться по ходу приложения еще 100500 раз. Чтобы избежать сильной связанности между представлением и логикой разделяют ответственности и в итоге окно отвечает само за себя.

Как же правильно? Да очень просто:

Сделаем обработчик события (его можно задать как в xaml так и внутри конструктора например, просто обратиться к событию `myTextbox.DoubleTapped += OnDoubleTapped`, и тогда не нужно будет привязывать через xaml, тут как удобно)

```
public class MyMainWindow : Window
{
   private void OnDoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      (sender as TextBox).Text = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   }
}
```

Теперь можно сделать ViewModel. Для начала реализует INPC и сделаем метод `SetProperty` чтобы было легче писать код и вызывать событие. Так же добавлю свойство `VMText` которое привяжем в xaml (назвал так для отличия свойства контрола и свойства вьюмодели)

```
public class MyMainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   private string _text;
   public string VMText { get => _text; set => SetProperty(ref _text, value); }
     
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
   protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
   {
     PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this. new(prop));
   }
   protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
   {
      if(field == value)
         return false;
      
      field = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(prop);
      return true;
   }
}
```

Можно перейти к `xaml` окна:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding VMText} DoubleTapped="OnDoubleTapped"/>
```

Теперь при вызове события `DoubleTapped` будет задаваться новый Guid и так же обновляться свойство во ViewModel которым вы можете пользоваться.

---

Сегодня Вы делаете проект на WPF, а завтра злой директор сказал: *надо на ASP.NET Core да еще и чтоб слайдер картинок был*, а у вас вся ViewModel захардкожена под WPF и слайдер реализован не внутри окна, а внутри ViewModel. Представляете сколько вы потратите времени просто на то чтобы переписать и захардкодить свою ViewModel под другой тип проекта **снова**?  Вот и я не представляю. Думайте о масштабировании

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137978/discussion-on-answer-by-aarnihauta-wpfmvvm-----control).