# Binding для события

Tags: c#, wpf

Вот мой DialogHost

```
<MaterialDesign:DialogHost Identifier="RenameDialog" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignEmbeddedDialogHost}" Panel.ZIndex="2002" DialogMargin="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Focusable="False" IsManipulationEnabled="True" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
            <MaterialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="150" Width="300" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" >
                        <MaterialDesign:ColorZone Content="{Binding Header}" Height="50" Mode="PrimaryLight" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneTime}" Margin="15 50 15 0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"></TextBox>
                        <Button x:Name="Dialog3" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" Content="Отмена" Margin="0 0 67 8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Command="MaterialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand" CommandParameter="Cancel" />
                        <Button x:Name="Dialog4" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" Content="OK"     Margin="0 0 8 8"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Command="MaterialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand" CommandParameter="OK" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </MaterialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContentTemplate>
        </MaterialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Вот-так я его вызываю:

```
DialogHost.Show(new { Header = "Header", Text = "Text" }, "RenameDialog");
```

Как сделать так чтобы, я мог третим параметром указывать обработчик TextChanged для TextBox?
Что-то типа такого

```
void TextBox_TextChanged(object NameTablesender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

```
DialogHost.Show(new { Header = "Header", Text = "Text", Changer = TextBox_TextChanged}, "RenameDialog");
```

Comment: Прибиндить `Text` к свойству с установкой `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` и вызывать свой код из сеттера.

Comment: @aepot Можете показать пример, а то я не очень понял как это сделать. Буду благодарен.

Comment: К сожалению сейчас набегами здесь, ищите информацию про привязку данных, вам нужно назначить `DataContext` и привязаться к свойству `{Binding ИмяСвойства, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`. Примеров полинтернета.

Comment: [Привязка данных](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/11.php)

Comment: [Вот еще про привязку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141941/373567)

Comment: [Еще привязки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1109976/373567), я так могу долго продолжать. Здесь только моих ответов с использованием привязок штук 30, а сколько их всего, я даже предположить боюсь.

Comment: @aepot А можно решить эту задачу через EventSetter или EventTrigger?

Comment: Можно, а зачем? Это как минимум не проще сделать.

Comment: @aepot Ну я хотел бы засунуть все в Wpf без MVVM

Comment: @aepot А можете продемонстрировать как, а то пробовал не вышло.

Comment: MVVM тут вообще не при чем. Я вам про привязки данных, которые к MVVM не имеют никакого отношения.

Comment: @aepot Так вы так и не использовали EventSetter, EventTrigger.

Comment: Если уж вам так нужен этот обработчик, почему его просто в xaml не прописать?

Comment: А зачем мне `EventTrigger`? Я их вообще никогда за ненадобностью не использую. Все интерфейсные кастомизации можнро прописать с помощью стиля со `Style.Triggers` прямо в XAML.

Comment: А вообще изучайте привязки данных и MVVM, без этих навыков вы только запутаетесь. Чем дальше, тем сложнее. WPF без привязок - вообще ад кромешный, а с использованием MaterialDesign - еще хуже. Как я понял, ответ ниже вам не подошел - удаляю.

Comment: А вообще фраза `Binding для собития` звучит как `Скакалка для сковородки`, совершенно никак не связанные друг с другом вещи. Отсюда вывод, вам надо изучить, что такое событие, и что такое и как работает `Binding`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте я покажу вам код, который имел в виду @aepot.

Вам нужно определить аргумент так:

```
class DialogArgs : VM
{
    public DialogArgs(Action<string> textChangeCallback) =>
        this.textChangeCallback = textChangeCallback ??
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(textChangeCallback));

    string header;
    public string Header
    {
        get => header;
        set => Set(ref header, value);
    }

    string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get => text;
        set
        {
            if (Set(ref text, value))
                textChangeCallback(text);
        }
    }

    private readonly Action<string> textChangeCallback;
}
```

Базовый класс `VM` с реализацией `INotifyPropertyChanged` вам пригодится и в других местах:

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value,
                         [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;

        field = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

а вместо `Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneTime}"` написать `Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Ну и показ диалога при этом будет выглядеть так:

```
DialogHost.Show(
    new DialogArgs(callback) { Header = "Header", Text = "Text" },
   "RenameDialog");
```

(например, я пробовал вместо `callback` написать `t => Debug.WriteLine(t)`, так что изменённый текст выводился в окошко Output).

---

Дополнение по результатам обсуждения в комментариях. Чтобы показывать ошибочный или неошибочный выбор имени, вам нужно добавить ещё пару свойств в `DialogArgs`:

```
    bool isGood;
    public bool IsGood
    {
        get => isGood;
        set => Set(ref isGood, value);
    }

    string errorText;
    public string ErrorText
    {
        get => errorText;
        set => Set(ref errorText, value);
    }
```

В вашем диалоге вы привязываете цвета к `IsGood` через конвертер (или пользуетесь триггером), и выводите текст из `ErrorText` в качестве сообщения об ошибке. А код вашего callback'а должен проверять имя, и устанавливать `IsGood` и `ErrorText`.

Например, так. Вот конвертер:

```
class HintColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type t, object parameter, CultureInfo ci) =>
        value is true ? Brushes.Black : Brushes.Red;
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type t, object parameter, CultureInfo ci) =>
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Textbox в коде диалога:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="15 50 15 0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"
         Foreground="{Binding IsGood, Converter={StaticResource HintColorConverter}}"
         materialDesign:HintAssist.Foreground="{Binding IsGood, Converter={StaticResource HintColorConverter}}"
         materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="{Binding IsGood, Converter={StaticResource HintColorConverter}}">
```

и в начала `DataTemplate`, конечно,

```
<DataTemplate.Resources>
    <local:HintColorConverter x:Key="HintColorConverter"/>
</DataTemplate.Resources>
```

Вот такое хитрое создание `DialogArgs` (считаем чётную длину правильной):

```
DialogArgs args = null;
args = new DialogArgs(t => args.IsGood = t.Length % 2 == 0) { Header = "Header" };
args.Text = "Text";
await DialogHost.Show(args, "RenameDialog");
```

Результат:

[image: в общем не особо хитро, асинхронная обработка была бы поинтереснее]

Можно и через триггеры, тогда вам не нужен конвертер:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="15 50 15 0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsGood}">
                    <DataTrigger.Value><sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean></DataTrigger.Value>
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="materialDesign:HintAssist.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

(не забудьте где-то вверху `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`)

Если проверка длинная, сделайте её асинхронной.

Comment: А где определять сам TextChanged?

Comment: Где захотите, лишь бы его сигнатура была `void f(string s)`.

Comment: Как Такое реализовать
`void TextBox_TextChanged(object NameTablesender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    TextBox text = (TextBox)NameTablesender;
                    text.SetValue(HintAssist.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
                    text.SetValue(HintAssist.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
                    text.SetValue(TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrushProperty, Brushes.Red);
                    text.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
`

Comment: @Qwerty если вы еще не поняли, вам не нужен обработчик события, а просто метод с нужным вам кодом.

Comment: @aepot Я понял, но как изменять свойства Textbox при изменении текста? нету sender

Comment: @Qwerty: А какое именно свойство вы хотите изменить? Вам нужно не напрямую работать со свойствами UI-элементов (мы ж не в Winforms), а привязывать их через Binding.

Comment: @VladD Я выше некоторое перечислил

Comment: Хм, вы меняете визуальные свойства. Это не дело VM-класса, заниматься представлением. Расскажите свою задачу более высокого уровня: что именно нужно реализовать?

Comment: @VladD У меня есть Dialog Host в нем есть TextBox, при вызове в нем будет название таблицы, когда я изменяю текст то програма должна проверять можно ли сохранить такое название, если нельзя переименовать таблицу, то "ОК" дезактивируется. При нажатии на "ОК" таблица переименовывается. Ну и если есть ошибка в названии то под TextBox выводиться текст ошибки.

Comment: @Qwerty: Смотрите дополнение в ответе

Comment: @Qwerty _но как изменять свойства Textbox при изменении текста_ - реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @VladD А как привязать цвет к IsGood через конвертер (или пользуетесь триггером)?

Comment: @Qwerty: Дополнил ответ, смотрите в конце

Comment: @VladD А как через тригеры?

Comment: @Qwerty: Написал и через триггеры тоже.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо.

Comment: @Qwerty: Пожалуйста!