# Занесение данных из одного окна в датагрид другой C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Не могу никак реализовать данный код. Помогите, есть 1 окно, содержащее датагрид и кнопку. Кнопка перенаправляет на модальное окно, в котором находятся текстбокс и кнопка. Вписывыаем данные в текстбокс, нажимаем кнопку - текст из этого текстбокса должен заноситься в датагрид. Как это реализовать? Целесообразно ли использовать датагрид?

Comment: `Как это реализовать?` - привязки! Забудьте вы про использование UI в коде, работайте с классами. `Целесообразно ли использовать датагрид?` - как источник данных, нет.

Comment: А как место хранения и дальнейшего экспорта данных?

Comment: `DatdGrid` использовать целесообразно только если вы редактируете данные прямо в таблице. Если у вас для редактирования данных сделано что-то своё, то проще использовать `ListBox` или `ListView`.

Comment: Данные - это классы, например вам надо вывести список пользователей в `ListBox`, вы делаете класс `User` с нужными свойствами и методами, далее делаете коллекцию, которая будет содержать в себе всех пользователей (`public ObservableCollection<User> Users {get; set;}`), задаете источник данных на нужный класс, сожержащем в себе `Users` (`DataContext = new SomeClass();`), ну и в XAML пишете `<ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Users}"/>`, все. Вот так у вас должно все быть, простой проект с привязкой, где данные отдельны от UI, а сейчас у вас получается так, что UI у вас хранит данные и это плохо!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `UI у вас хранит данные и это плохо` - во-первых, это вангование, а не факт, хоть я и согласен, что это так и есть с вероятностью 99%. Во-вторых все-таки если так хочется помочь автору, лучше покажите автору простой и понятный пример в ответе. Подозреваю, что качественный ответ с примером кода будет автору понятнее, чем стена комментов. Расценивайте пожалуйста это не как наезд, а как конструктивное предложение. :)

Comment: @aepot 1. 100% используется UI, ибо `текст из этого текстбокса должен заноситься в датагрид`. 2. Я не вижу смысла в ответе, ибо 1. На SO есть **уйма** ответов, как и что делать, что, опять повторять одно и тоже? Ну такое себе занятие. Уж лучше найти годный ответ и закрыть дубликатом. 2. Я не вижу желание автора разбираться в этом, и я уверен, что если написать ответ, то он его не поймем, скопирует бездумно и дальше будет писать `myTextBox.Text = "текст";`, может и ошибаюсь, да, но раз так, то тогда здесь достаточно "автор, посмотрите, что такое `binding` и как положено использовать WPF".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1109976/373567 вот кстати, но я уже проголосовал.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вот еще пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219057/373567, но все эти примеры без отдельного окна. А как с отдельным окном без нарушения MVVM решить - я не нашел.

Comment: @aepot В этом вся и проблема) Тут нету вопроса про MVVM, а есть вопрос про передачу данных из класса в класс, также увы, не подходит то, чем вы пытаетесь закрыть (учебное задание). Может тогда [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/835214/220553) (или аналогичным) закрыть?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ там не WPF. Все аналогичные я как раз по винформам вижу, а по WPF - нет. Может все-таки ответ дать? Без MVVM и всякого такого, а просто с привязкой коллекции.

Comment: @aepot А чем WPF отличается от чего-либо другого? Передача данных из класса в класс везде одинакова, особенно если брать базовую работу с UI WPF. Ну а так, я вам не запрещаю, делайте ответ если хотите, только сами понимаете, что вы сейчас потратите время на дублирование того, что сами писали много раз)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ к сожалению, качество вопроса не позволяет однозначно понять, что именно хочет узнать автор и что у него не получается. Поэтому я таки подожду его реакцию на комментарии.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ aepot спасибо за ответы. Я освою MVVM, буду делать привязки. Как вы сказали, с UI работать буду по минимуму. В формулировке вопроса, я имел ввиду, грубо говоря, использование одной переменной одного окна в другом окне. Больше моя голова придумать не могла. Спасибо за ответ, еще раз