# Доступ у event c# mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Имею вот такой ивент во вьюмодели

```
public delegate void LostMouseCaptureEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
public event LostMouseCaptureEvent LostMouseCapture;
```

хочу вызывать его из code behind(.xaml.cs)

```
private void constructionView_LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

       LostMouseCapture?.Invoke(sender, e);
     
    }
```

Как должно быть правильно? использую mvvm и c#

Comment: Опишите интерфейс для вьюмодели, после чего в данном методе, сделайте каст Data context,  к интерфейсу, и вызовите нужный метод.

Answer (score 1):

Техническая сторона вопроса:

Для вызова кода VM из View используются команды. Например, возьмите реализацию `ICommand` через `RelayCommand` (например, [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852526/10105)), выставьте в VM свойство типа `ICommand`, и вызывайте у него метод `Execute`.

`ICommand` прекрасно можно привязать к свойству `Command` кнопки, но если вы хотите привязать к событию в UI, вам понадобится подключить пакет [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/), добавить в корневом элементе (окне или UserControl'е) пространство имён `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"` и использовать код наподобие такого:

```xml
<Grid Name="constructionView">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostMouseCapture">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding InvokeOnLostCaptureCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    ...
```

Ну или если хотите в code behind, то вам придётся закастить `DataContext` к его настоящему типу, и вызвать команду «вручную» (что, скажем прямо, крайне неизящно).

---

Смысловая сторона вопроса:

Вопрос о том, где находится mouse capture — это вопрос компетенции View, и вовсе не должен спускаться на уровень VM. Вы делаете что-то неправильно: информация о том, что происходит с мышью, должна по идее быть обработана во View.