# C# WPF как получить доступ к нескольким textbox внутри datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Сразу скажу что я только учусь (самообучение), так вот у меня есть DataGrid в котором есть кнопка и 2 textbox-а, я получил доступ к кнопке и первому textbox-у, не могу понять как получать доступ к 2-му texbox?

xaml:

```
 <Grid Margin="10">
    <StackPanel Margin="5">
        <Grid Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Name="buttonAddGame"  Width="100"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Добавить Игру" Click="buttonAddGame_Click"/>
            <TextBox Name="textAddGame" Width="100"  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="новая игра" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin=" 130 0 0 0"/>
            <Button Name="update" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Обновить" Click="update_Click" Margin="350 0 0 0" Cursor="Hand" />
        </Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="lbMain" Margin="10" Width="auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Игра" Binding="{Binding Path='Name'}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Донат" Binding="{Binding Path='Donate'}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Голос" Binding="{Binding Path='Poll'}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Время Стрима" Binding="{Binding Path='StreamTime'}" IsReadOnly="True" />

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button  Name="btnChange" Content="Изменить" Click="btnChange_Click" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="+ Донат" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox x:Name="textUpdateDonate"  Width="100" Text=""  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="+ Голос" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox x:Name="textUpdatePoll"  Width="100" Text="" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Margin="0 50 0 0" x:Name="close" Content="Выйти" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="close_Click" Background="#FFFDFDFD" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="#DD6F6F6F" Cursor="Hand"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

C#:

```
private void btnChange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //var dataRow = (Game)((Button)e.Source).DataContext;
        object ordinal = e.OriginalSource;
        DataGrid dataGrid = FindParent<DataGrid>((DependencyObject)ordinal);
        TextBox tb = FindVisualChild<TextBox>(dataGrid);

        MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);
    }

    private void close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    private void update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lbMain.Items.Refresh();
    }

    public static parentItem FindParent<parentItem>(DependencyObject obj)
        where parentItem : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject objToRet = obj;
        while (!(objToRet is parentItem))
        {
            objToRet = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(objToRet);
            if (objToRet == null) return null;
        }
        return (parentItem)objToRet;
    }

    public static childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
        where childItem : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is childItem)
                return (childItem)child;
            else
            {
                childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Класс Game:

```
public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public double Donate
    {
        get { return donate; }
        set
        {
            donate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Donate");
        }
    }
    public int Poll
    {
        get { return poll; }
        set
        {
            poll = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Poll");
        }
    }

    public double StreamTime
    {
        get { return streamTime; }
        set
        {
            streamTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StreamTime");
        }

    }
    public string TextBoxDonate
    {
        get { return textBoxDonate; }
        set
        {
            textBoxDonate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TextBoxDonate");
        }
    }

    public string TextBoxPoll
    {
        get { return textBoxPoll; }
        set
        {
            textBoxPoll = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TextBoxPoll");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
```

[image: вот так выглядит приложение]

собственно по нажатию на кнопку я хочу получить доступ к тексту который введен в обоих textbox-ах, я так понял нужно что то переписать, но голова уже не соображает

Comment: **Весь** ваш код замените на `DataContext = класс;`, где `класс` это простой класс с нужными публичными свойствами для привязки, далее в XAML все `x:Name` заменяете на привязки к нужным свойствам, например `x:Name="lbMain"` меняете на `ItemsSource = "{Binding Items}"` (Items - свойство коллекции в классе), все, у вас несколько строк кода, вы не делаете костыли по типу поиска элемента, не храните данные в UI, у вас все на своих местах и все как надо. Имея это уже дальше можете работать, например `Click` заменить на `Command`, тогда передача данных будет просто `CommandParameter = "{Binding}"`.

Comment: проблема в том что, я только учусь и понимаю только на рабочих примерах, когда искал решение нашел такую реализацию как у меня в коде, да костыль на работает =) Если не затруднит можно больше кода для примера ?

Comment: `я только учусь` - по этой причине я и говорю вам, что вы делаете все не так, научитесь сразу использовать WPF правильно. `больше кода для примера` - куда еще больше?) Я вам считай пошаговую инструкцию дал, можете посмотреть также мои ответы по WPF, там найдете кучу полезного. Зовется это все "Привязки". Вы начните делать, а если возникнут вопросы, пишите, помогу.

Comment: у меня проблема сразу на первом шаге =) DataContext = класс..
у меня уже есть класс Game (добавил его в вопрос сверху), при попытке сделать DataContext = Game; висит ошибка : Game является тип, который недопустим в данном контексте.

Comment: Наверно потому, что `new Game();`? Как в C# инициализируются классы? Ну и `DataContext` должен задаваться классу окна (про это я забыл сказать).

Comment: CommandParameter = "{Binding}" можно подробней ? это в кнопке мы меняем click на CommandParameter = "{Binding}" правильно? а что в биндинг прописываем ? или это уже готовый код ?

Comment: Смотрите, `Click` - это событие, стандартное, простое событие, его аналогом в привязках являются команды, где вы в классе делаете публичное свойство (помним, что привязки доступны только к ним) с типом `ICommand`, далее вам нужно реализовать эту команду любым удобным для вас способов, например можно взять [от сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852526/220553) класс `RelayCommand`, дальше вам надо создать эту команду, указав какой метод будет использоваться. В XAML вы привязываете команду (`Command = "{Binding MyCommand}"`), ну и передаете параметры через `CommandParameter`.

Comment: `{Binding}` - если не указано чего либо, то это означает "Текущий объект целиком", в вашем случае это будет `Game`, значит и в команде получайте тип `Game`. Если нужно конкретное значение, то указывайте его, например `{Binding Name}`, будет вам имя, в обработчике команды тип тогда `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

во-первых, в xaml коде, там, где нужные textbox, нужно было дописать:

```
<TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=TextBoxDonate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
```

после чего написанное в данном текст боксе уже отображалось в поле TextBoxDonate, а именно:

```
 var ordinal = e.OriginalSource;
        

        if (ordinal is Button)
        {
            DataGridRow dataGrid = FindParent<DataGridRow>((DependencyObject)ordinal);
            
            if (dataGrid != null)
            {
                int idx = lbMain.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(dataGrid);
                var thisGame = Gamess[idx];

                //thisGame.TextBoxDonate и есть наш textbox
            }
        }
```