# C#/WPF+MVMM материалы

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

хочу попробовать написать приложение на C#/WPF + MVMM. С чего начать и какие материалы(книги, статьи) посоветуете??

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567 для начала почитайте, что такое MVVM и зачем оно нужно. Затем познакомьтесь с привязками данных `Binding`, что такое `DataContext`, `INotifyPropertyChanged` и с чем это едят. Попутно знакомьтесь с XAML, стилями, словарями ресурсов, и дело пойдёт.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852526/220553

Comment: Я учился по видео на Ютубе. Канал Павла Ш. очень мне помог разобраться во многих вещах по mvvm.