# Отрисовка прямоугольников через c# код

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть у меня такой код:
Xaml:

```
 <Canvas Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=image}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=image}">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <VisualBrush>
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <Image x:Name="image" Source="/Resource/***.JPG"/>
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Canvas.Background>

            <Path x:Name="path" Fill="Red" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=image}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=image}">
                <Path.Data>
                    <GeometryGroup>
                        // Как вывести сюда прямоугольники?
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>

        </Canvas>
```

Не принципиально в то место,просто мне нужно в канвас через код выводить некоторый граф,где узлы это квадратики

С#

```
 List<RectangleGeometry> myRectangleGeometry = new List<RectangleGeometry>();

                foreach (GraphNode gn in graphNodes)
                {
                    // Вывод на экран
                    myRectangleGeometry.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(gn.XCoord, gn.YCoord, 50, 50)));
                }
```

Comment: Скорее вам надо ItemsSource с Canvas в качестве панели, примерно как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо,стало немного понятнее как все работает)Квадратики рисуются