# Рисование на картинке контролов, которые можно передвигать

Tags: wpf, .net

В общем, у меня есть картинка и массив координат.

Может быть 4 координаты и в этом случае нужно нарисовать прямоугольник, а может быть координата высоты и в этом случае нужно нарисовать линию.

Все бы ничего, но нужно дать возможность это передвигать мышкой.

А потом, пользователь может нажать сохранить и вся эта разметка отрисуется на исходном образе.

Как это можно реализовать средствами WPF через MVVM?

Comment: Вот для начала: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647/218063

Comment: Ну и надо иметь в VM не массив координат, а массив классов, для линии это будет один класс, для прямоугольника — другой и т. д. В V части будет выбираться нужный шаблон в зависимости от типа объекта с помощью DataTemplate.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, т.е я должен завезти ItemsControl, у него задать, что Canvas является хостом. У Canvas я должен буду менять Background, а в ItemTemplate описать свои контролы?

Comment: *У Canvas я должен буду менять Background* — зачем? *а в ItemTemplate описать свои контролы?* — ну скорее не в `ItemTemplate`, а в ресурсы положить `DataTemplate` для разных `DataType`, примерно как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP "зачем"--- ну мне же нужно отрисовать картинку, а на ней уже по координатам расположить контролы.

Comment: А, картинку... Ну я бы сделал один Grid, в него Image с картинкой и в него же ItemsSource со всем вышеперечисленным

Comment: @АндрейNOP, еще вопрос: А как можно дать пользователю возможность ресайзить контрол?

Comment: Навскидку, отображать маркеры и перетаскивать их