# Перемещение элементов WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, label

Есть WrapPanel заполнена Label, в итоге получено поле 10x10. Label создаются динамически, к ним цепляется два ивента

```
 la.Drop += lbl_Drop;
 la.MouseDown += lbl_MouseDown;

 private void lbl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
    Label lbl = (Label)sender;
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbl, lbl.Content, DragDropEffects.All);
 }

 private void lbl_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {
     ((Label)sender).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
 }
```

При попытке его перетянуть появляется значок, который указывает что так делать нельзя, в чём проблема?

Comment: А почему это вообще должно работать? Вы перемещаете строку, почему это должно перемещать контрол?

Comment: Вот код: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444924/10105, он умеет перемещать даже между окнами. Никакого `DoDragDrop` и тому подобной тяжёлой артиллерии не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы дроп сработал, нужно включить [AllowDrop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.allowdrop.aspx) у перетаскиваемого объекта и источника. Из описания события [Drop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.drop.aspx):

> Чтобы событие Drop произошло и вызвало обработчик, значение AllowDrop для UIElement, являющегося целевым объектом перетаскивания, а также источника действия перетаскивания, должно быть true.

И Drop надо обрабатывать на элементе, который принимает, а не на перетаскиваемом. Из той же статьи, описание эвента Drop:

> Происходит, когда система ввода сообщает об основном событии перетаскивания, в котором данный элемент является местом назначения.