# WPF. DragAndDrop из разных панелей

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-n-drop

Есть контрол:

```
<UserControl /*namespaces*/ 
            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            AllowDrop="True">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageUrl}" AllowDrop="True"></Image>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Главное окно, которое использует этот контрол:

```
<Window /*namespaces*/>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Name="ItemsControl">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.15*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <local:MyCustomControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Drop="MyCustomControl_Drop"></local:MyCustomControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

При старте приложения заполняется первая колонка топ-грида, то есть в первой колонке заполняется UniformGrid так:

```
ItemsControl.Items.Add(new MyCustomControl() { /* properties_initialization*/});
```

Во второй колонке топ-грида, создается ещё один внутренний грид (`<Grid Grid.Column="1">`)

Как видно из разметки во внутреннем гриде находится один мой контрол (в этот контрол нужно разрешить `Drop`):

```
<local:MyCustomControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Drop="MyCustomControl_Drop"></local:MyCustomControl>
```

**Задача:** из первой колонки топ-грида, взять item из UniformGrid и `Drop`-нуть во вторую колонку, во внутренний грид, в мой контрол `<local:MyCustomControl...`
[image: Задача]

**Что получается сейчас**: как видно из разметки контрола везде прописан атрибут `AllowDrop="True"` - который должен разрешать `Drop`. Но если перемещать элемент внутри UniformGrid то в нем везде Drop разрешен. А в момент когда `<local:MyCustomControl>` (из второй колонки) ещё не заполнен, `Drop` почему-то запрещен и можно дропнуть только на границу контрола..

Если дропать непосредственно на часть где изображение, то дроп тоже разрешен, но на момент старта там пусто, по этому приходится дропать только на границу..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал ко всем гридам дописывать `AllowDrop="True"` и описывать контрол так: `<local:MyCustomControl AllowDrop="True"` - без успешно.

**Вопрос:** почему так?

Comment: Вот по теме: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444924/10105, тут можно даже между окнами перетаскивать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, у вас контрол не содержит установленного фона. Контрол без фона является «прозрачным» для событий от мыши, и таким образом не получает сообщения drag-and-drop.

Для того, чтобы контролу доставлялись мышиные события, ему нужен непустой `Background`. Для вашего случая — `Background="Transparent"`.